# How to measure time in milliseconds using ANSI C?

Tags: c, portability, time-precision

Using only ANSI C, is there any way to measure time with milliseconds precision or more? I was browsing time.h but I only found second precision functions.

Comment: Note the difference between precision and accuracy. You can get a time with millisecond *precision* by taking the time in seconds and multiplying by 1000, but that's no use. ms precision functions don't necessarily have ms accuracy - although they generally do better than 1s accuracy.

Comment: The simple answer is NO, ANSI C does not support millisecond precision or better. The more complex answer depends on what you are trying to do - frankly the whole area is a nightmare - even if you allow the use of the widely available Posix functions. You use the term "measure" so I assume that you are interested in an interval rather than "wall clock" time. But are you attempting to measure an absolute time period or cpu usage by your process?

Comment: Just wanted to say to SOF just saved my bacon, again ;-)

Comment: This Q&A is out-of-date since ~2011 with the release of C11. @Ciro Santilli Путлер has presented an ANSI/ISO [C11 solution here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36095407/4561887) with C11's `timespec_get()`.

Comment: See also this more-relevant question [Get a timestamp in C in microseconds?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5833094/4561887). @Ciro Santilli Путлер [presents a concise demo of C11's `timespec_get()` function here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36095514/4561887). And I have also presented a detailed answer with the C11 function `timespec_get()` (ok) and the Linux/POSIX function `clock_gettime()` (even better!) here: [How to get a simple timestamp in C](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67731965/4561887).

Comment: In [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67731965/4561887), I demonstrate timestamps for millisecond, microsecond, and nanosecond timestamps via my functions `millis()`, `micros()`, and `nanos()`, respectively. On my system, the best resolution possible is **~20ns**, but the resolution is hardware-dependent and can vary from system to system. These solutions are the modern techniques useful today.

Answer (score 109, accepted):

There is no ANSI C function that provides better than 1 second time resolution but the POSIX function [`gettimeofday`](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/000095399/functions/gettimeofday.html) provides microsecond resolution.  The clock function only measures the amount of time that a process has spent executing and is not accurate on many systems.

You can use this function like this:

```
struct timeval tval_before, tval_after, tval_result;

gettimeofday(&tval_before, NULL);

// Some code you want to time, for example:
sleep(1);

gettimeofday(&tval_after, NULL);

timersub(&tval_after, &tval_before, &tval_result);

printf("Time elapsed: %ld.%06ld\n", (long int)tval_result.tv_sec, (long int)tval_result.tv_usec);
```

This returns `Time elapsed: 1.000870` on my machine.

Comment: Slight caveat: gettimeofday() is not monotonic, meaning it can jump around (and even go backwards) if, for example, your machine is attempting to keep synchronisation with a network time server or some other time source.

Comment: To be precise: In ISO C99 (which I think is compatible in this part with ANSI C) there isn't even a guarantee of *any* time resolution. (ISO C99, 7.23.1p4)

Comment: It's worth noting that `timeval::tv_usec` is always under one second, it's looping. I.e. in order to take differences of time larger than 1 sec, you should: `long usec_diff = (e.tv_sec - s.tv_sec)*1000000 + (e.tv_usec - s.tv_usec);`

Comment: @Dipstick: But note that e.g. NTP never moves your clock backwards until you explicitly tell it to do so.

Comment: @Dipstick have we found a way to go back in time!?

Comment: @AlexanderMalakhov time subtraction logic is incapsulated inside `timersub` function. We can use `tval_result` values (tv_sec and tv_usec) as-is.

Comment: Can anyone explain what 06 does in %ld.%06ld?

Comment: This answer is out-of-date as of C11. I've presented a detailed answer with the C11 function `timespec_get()` (ok) and the Linux/POSIX function `clock_gettime()` (even better!) here: [How to get a simple timestamp in C](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67731965/4561887), for millisecond (`millis()`), microsecond (`micros()`), and nanosecond (`nanos()`) timestamps. On my system, the best resolution possible is **~20ns**, but the resolution is hardware-dependent and can vary from system to system.

Comment: And @Ciro Santilli Путлер has presented an ANSI/ISO [C11 solution here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36095407/4561887). These solutions are the modern techniques useful today.

Answer (score 54):

```
#include <time.h>
clock_t uptime = clock() / (CLOCKS_PER_SEC / 1000);
```

Comment: CLOCKS_PER_SEC is set to 1000000 on many systems. Print its value to be sure before you use it in this fashion.

Comment: Since it's clocks per second it doesn't matter what value it is, the resulting value from clock() / CLOCKS_PER_SEC will be in seconds(at least it should be).  Dividing by 1000 turns that into milliseconds.

Comment: According to the C Reference Manual, clock_t values can wrap around starting at around 36 minutes. If you are measuring a long computation you need to be aware of this.

Comment: Also beware that the integer division `CLOCKS_PER_SEC / 1000` might possibly be inexact which could affect the end result (though in my experience `CLOCKS_PER_SEC` has always been a multiple of 1000). Doing `(1000 * clock()) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC` is less susceptible to division inexactness, but on the other hand is more susceptible to overflow. Just some issues to consider.

Comment: Doesn't this measure cpu time and not wall time?

Comment: `clock()` [measures](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27178789/23715) wall-time on Windows and CPU time on most other popular OSes.

Answer (score 32):

I always use the clock_gettime() function, returning time from the CLOCK_MONOTONIC clock. The time returned is the amount of time, in seconds and nanoseconds, since some unspecified point in the past, such as system startup of the epoch.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <time.h>

int64_t timespecDiff(struct timespec *timeA_p, struct timespec *timeB_p)
{
  return ((timeA_p->tv_sec * 1000000000) + timeA_p->tv_nsec) -
           ((timeB_p->tv_sec * 1000000000) + timeB_p->tv_nsec);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  struct timespec start, end;
  clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &start);

  // Some code I am interested in measuring 

  clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &end);

  uint64_t timeElapsed = timespecDiff(&end, &start);
}
```

Comment: clock_gettime() is not ANSI C.

Comment: Also CLOCK_MONOTONIC is not implemented on many systems (including many Linux platforms).

Comment: @PowerApp101 There's no good/robust ANSI C way of doing this. Many of the other answers rely on POSIX rather than ANCI C. That being said, I believe that today.

@Dipstick Today, I believe most modern platforms[citation needed] support `clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, ...)` and there's even the feature test macro `_POSIX_MONOTONIC_CLOCK`.

Answer (score 28):

**Implementing a portable solution**

As it was already mentioned here that there is no proper ANSI solution with sufficient precision for the time measurement problem, I want to write about the ways how to get a portable and, if possible, a high-resolution time measurement solution.

**Monotonic clock vs. time stamps**

Generally speaking there are two ways of time measurement:

- monotonic clock;
- current (date)time stamp.

The first one uses a monotonic clock counter (sometimes it is called a tick counter) which counts ticks with a predefined frequency, so if you have a ticks value and the frequency is known, you can easily convert ticks to elapsed time. It is actually not guaranteed that a monotonic clock reflects the current system time in any way, it may also count ticks since a system startup. But it guarantees that a clock is always run up in an increasing fashion regardless of the system state. Usually the frequency is bound to a hardware high-resolution source, that's why it provides a high accuracy (depends on hardware, but most of the modern hardware has no problems with high-resolution clock sources).

The second way provides a (date)time value based on the current system clock value. It may also have a high resolution, but it has one major drawback: this kind of time value can be affected by different system time adjustments, i.e. time zone change, daylight saving time (DST) change, NTP server update, system hibernation and so on. In some circumstances you can get a negative elapsed time value which can lead to an undefined behavior. Actually this kind of time source is less reliable than the first one.

So the first rule in time interval measuring is to use a monotonic clock if possible. It usually has a high precision, and it is reliable by design.

**Fallback strategy**

When implementing a portable solution it is worth to consider a fallback strategy: use a monotonic clock if available and fallback to time stamps approach if there is no monotonic clock in the system.

**Windows**

There is a great article called [Acquiring high-resolution time stamps](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windows/desktop/dn553408(v=vs.85).aspx) on MSDN about time measurement on Windows which describes all the details you may need to know about software and hardware support. To acquire a high precision time stamp on Windows you should:

- query a timer frequency (ticks per second) with [QueryPerformanceFrequency](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windows/desktop/ms644905(v=vs.85).aspx):

  ```
  LARGE_INTEGER tcounter;
  LARGE_INTEGER freq;    

  if (QueryPerformanceFrequency (&tcounter) != 0)
      freq = tcounter.QuadPart;
  ```

  The timer frequency is fixed on the system boot so you need to get it only once.
- query the current ticks value with [QueryPerformanceCounter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windows/desktop/ms644904(v=vs.85).aspx):

  ```
  LARGE_INTEGER tcounter;
  LARGE_INTEGER tick_value;

  if (QueryPerformanceCounter (&tcounter) != 0)
      tick_value = tcounter.QuadPart;
  ```
- scale the ticks to elapsed time, i.e. to microseconds:

  ```
  LARGE_INTEGER usecs = (tick_value - prev_tick_value) / (freq / 1000000);
  ```

According to Microsoft you should not have any problems with this approach on Windows XP and later versions in most cases. But you can also use two fallback solutions on Windows:

- [GetTickCount](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724408.aspx) provides the number of milliseconds that have elapsed since the system was started. It wraps every 49.7 days, so be careful in measuring longer intervals.
- [GetTickCount64](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724411.aspx) is a 64-bit version of `GetTickCount`, but it is available starting from Windows Vista and above.

**OS X (macOS)**

OS X (macOS) has its own Mach absolute time units which represent a monotonic clock. The best way to start is the Apple's article [Technical Q&A QA1398: Mach Absolute Time Units](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/qa/qa1398/_index.html) which describes (with the code examples) how to use Mach-specific API to get monotonic ticks. There is also a local question about it called [clock_gettime alternative in Mac OS X](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5167269/clock-gettime-alternative-in-mac-os-x) which at the end may leave you a bit confused what to do with the possible value overflow because the counter frequency is used in the form of numerator and denominator. So, a short example how to get elapsed time:

- get the clock frequency numerator and denominator:

  ```
  #include <mach/mach_time.h>
  #include <stdint.h>

  static uint64_t freq_num   = 0;
  static uint64_t freq_denom = 0;

  void init_clock_frequency ()
  {
      mach_timebase_info_data_t tb;

      if (mach_timebase_info (&tb) == KERN_SUCCESS && tb.denom != 0) {
          freq_num   = (uint64_t) tb.numer;
          freq_denom = (uint64_t) tb.denom;
      }
  }
  ```

  You need to do that only once.
- query the current tick value with `mach_absolute_time`:

  ```
  uint64_t tick_value = mach_absolute_time ();
  ```
- scale the ticks to elapsed time, i.e. to microseconds, using previously queried numerator and denominator:

  ```
  uint64_t value_diff = tick_value - prev_tick_value;

  /* To prevent overflow */
  value_diff /= 1000;

  value_diff *= freq_num;
  value_diff /= freq_denom;
  ```

  The main idea to prevent an overflow is to scale down the ticks to desired accuracy before using the numerator and denominator. As the initial timer resolution is in nanoseconds, we divide it by `1000` to get microseconds. You can find the same approach used in Chromium's [time_mac.c](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/base/+/master/time/time_mac.cc). If you really need a nanosecond accuracy consider reading the [How can I use mach_absolute_time without overflowing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23378063/how-can-i-use-mach-absolute-time-without-overflowing).

**Linux and UNIX**

The `clock_gettime` call is your best way on any POSIX-friendly system. It can query time from different clock sources, and the one we need is `CLOCK_MONOTONIC`. Not all systems which have `clock_gettime` support `CLOCK_MONOTONIC`, so the first thing you need to do is to check its availability:

- if `_POSIX_MONOTONIC_CLOCK` is defined to a value `>= 0` it means that `CLOCK_MONOTONIC` is avaiable;
- if `_POSIX_MONOTONIC_CLOCK` is defined to `0` it means that you should additionally check if it works at runtime, I suggest to use `sysconf`:

  ```
  #include <unistd.h>

  #ifdef _SC_MONOTONIC_CLOCK
  if (sysconf (_SC_MONOTONIC_CLOCK) > 0) {
      /* A monotonic clock presents */
  }
  #endif
  ```
- otherwise a monotonic clock is not supported and you should use a fallback strategy (see below).

Usage of `clock_gettime` is pretty straight forward:

- get the time value:

  ```
  #include <time.h>
  #include <sys/time.h>
  #include <stdint.h>

  uint64_t get_posix_clock_time ()
  {
      struct timespec ts;

      if (clock_gettime (CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &ts) == 0)
          return (uint64_t) (ts.tv_sec * 1000000 + ts.tv_nsec / 1000);
      else
          return 0;
  }
  ```

  I've scaled down the time to microseconds here.
- calculate the difference with the previous time value received the same way:

  ```
  uint64_t prev_time_value, time_value;
  uint64_t time_diff;

  /* Initial time */
  prev_time_value = get_posix_clock_time ();

  /* Do some work here */

  /* Final time */
  time_value = get_posix_clock_time ();

  /* Time difference */
  time_diff = time_value - prev_time_value;
  ```

The best fallback strategy is to use the `gettimeofday` call: it is not a monotonic, but it provides quite a good resolution. The idea is the same as with `clock_gettime`, but to get a time value you should:

```
#include <time.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <stdint.h>

uint64_t get_gtod_clock_time ()
{
    struct timeval tv;

    if (gettimeofday (&tv, NULL) == 0)
        return (uint64_t) (tv.tv_sec * 1000000 + tv.tv_usec);
    else
        return 0;
}
```

Again, the time value is scaled down to microseconds.

**SGI IRIX**

[IRIX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IRIX) has the `clock_gettime` call, but it lacks `CLOCK_MONOTONIC`. Instead it has its own monotonic clock source defined as `CLOCK_SGI_CYCLE` which you should use instead of `CLOCK_MONOTONIC` with `clock_gettime`.

**Solaris and HP-UX**

Solaris has its own high-resolution timer interface `gethrtime` which returns the current timer value in nanoseconds. Though the newer versions of Solaris may have `clock_gettime`, you can stick to `gethrtime` if you need to support old Solaris versions.

Usage is simple:

```
#include <sys/time.h>

void time_measure_example ()
{
    hrtime_t prev_time_value, time_value;
    hrtime_t time_diff;

    /* Initial time */
    prev_time_value = gethrtime ();

    /* Do some work here */

    /* Final time */
    time_value = gethrtime ();

    /* Time difference */
    time_diff = time_value - prev_time_value;
}
```

HP-UX lacks `clock_gettime`, but it supports `gethrtime` which you should use in the same way as on Solaris.

**BeOS**

[BeOS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BeOS) also has its own high-resolution timer interface `system_time` which returns the number of microseconds have elapsed since the computer was booted.

Example usage:

```
#include <kernel/OS.h>

void time_measure_example ()
{
    bigtime_t prev_time_value, time_value;
    bigtime_t time_diff;

    /* Initial time */
    prev_time_value = system_time ();

    /* Do some work here */

    /* Final time */
    time_value = system_time ();

    /* Time difference */
    time_diff = time_value - prev_time_value;
}
```

**OS/2**

[OS/2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OS/2) has its own API to retrieve high-precision time stamps:

- query a timer frequency (ticks per unit) with `DosTmrQueryFreq` (for GCC compiler):

  ```
  #define INCL_DOSPROFILE
  #define INCL_DOSERRORS
  #include <os2.h>
  #include <stdint.h>

  ULONG freq;

  DosTmrQueryFreq (&freq);
  ```
- query the current ticks value with `DosTmrQueryTime`:

  ```
  QWORD    tcounter;
  unit64_t time_low;
  unit64_t time_high;
  unit64_t timestamp;

  if (DosTmrQueryTime (&tcounter) == NO_ERROR) {
      time_low  = (unit64_t) tcounter.ulLo;
      time_high = (unit64_t) tcounter.ulHi;

      timestamp = (time_high << 32) | time_low;
  }
  ```
- scale the ticks to elapsed time, i.e. to microseconds:

  ```
  uint64_t usecs = (prev_timestamp - timestamp) / (freq / 1000000);
  ```

**Example implementation**

You can take a look at the [plibsys](https://github.com/saprykin/plibsys) library which implements all the described above strategies (see ptimeprofiler*.c for details).

Comment: "there is no proper ANSI solution with sufficient precision for the time measurement problem": there is C11 `timespec_get`:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/36095407/895245

Comment: This is still a wrong way to measure time of code execution. `timespec_get` is not monotonic.

Answer (score 18):

**`timespec_get` from C11**

Returns up to nanoseconds, rounded to the resolution of the implementation.

Looks like an ANSI ripoff from POSIX' `clock_gettime`.

Example: a `printf` is done every 100ms on Ubuntu 15.10:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

static long get_nanos(void) {
    struct timespec ts;
    timespec_get(&ts, TIME_UTC);
    return (long)ts.tv_sec * 1000000000L + ts.tv_nsec;
}

int main(void) {
    long nanos;
    long last_nanos;
    long start;
    nanos = get_nanos();
    last_nanos = nanos;
    start = nanos;
    while (1) {
        nanos = get_nanos();
        if (nanos - last_nanos > 100000000L) {
            printf("current nanos: %ld\n", nanos - start);
            last_nanos = nanos;
        }
    }
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

The [C11 N1570 standard draft](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) 7.27.2.5 "The timespec_get function says":

> If base is TIME_UTC, the tv_sec member is set to the number of seconds since an
>   implementation defined epoch, truncated to a whole value and the tv_nsec member is
>   set to the integral number of nanoseconds, rounded to the resolution of the system clock. (321)
>
> 321) Although a struct timespec object describes times with nanosecond resolution, the available
>   resolution is system dependent and may even be greater than 1 second.

C++11 also got `std::chrono::high_resolution_clock`: [C++ Cross-Platform High-Resolution Timer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1487695/c-cross-platform-high-resolution-timer)

**glibc 2.21 implementation**

Can be found under [`sysdeps/posix/timespec_get.c`](https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=sysdeps/posix/timespec_get.c;h=2609b2e72998aacc4ea537430c2278ebbf51b83a;hb=4e42b5b8f89f0e288e68be7ad70f9525aebc2cff) as:

```
int
timespec_get (struct timespec *ts, int base)
{
  switch (base)
    {
    case TIME_UTC:
      if (__clock_gettime (CLOCK_REALTIME, ts) < 0)
        return 0;
      break;

    default:
      return 0;
    }

  return base;
}
```

so clearly:

- only `TIME_UTC` is currently supported
- it forwards to `__clock_gettime (CLOCK_REALTIME, ts)`, which is a POSIX API: http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/clock_getres.html

  Linux x86-64 has a `clock_gettime` system call.

  Note that this is not a fail-proof micro-benchmarking method because:

  - `man clock_gettime` says that this measure may have discontinuities if you change some system time setting while your program runs. This should be a rare event of course, and you might be able to ignore it.
  - this measures wall time, so if the scheduler decides to forget about your task, it will appear to run for longer.

  For those reasons `getrusage()` might be a better better POSIX benchmarking tool, despite it's lower microsecond maximum precision.

  More information at: [Measure time in Linux - time vs clock vs getrusage vs clock_gettime vs gettimeofday vs timespec_get?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12392278/measure-time-in-linux-getrusage-vs-clock-gettime-vs-clock-vs-gettimeofday)

Comment: this is the right answer as of 2017, even MSVC has this function; in terms of benchmarking seek out something that reads chip register (newer versions of x86 processors with PT extensions, and the corresponding newer versions of Linux kernel/perf)

Answer (score 5):

The accepted answer is good enough.But my solution is more simple.I just test in Linux, use gcc (Ubuntu 7.2.0-8ubuntu3.2) 7.2.0.

Alse use `gettimeofday`, the `tv_sec` is the part of second, and the `tv_usec` is **microseconds**, not **milliseconds**.

```
long currentTimeMillis() {
  struct timeval time;
  gettimeofday(&time, NULL);

  return time.tv_sec * 1000 + time.tv_usec / 1000;
}

int main() {
  printf("%ld\n", currentTimeMillis());
  // wait 1 second
  sleep(1);
  printf("%ld\n", currentTimeMillis());
  return 0;
 }
```

It print:

`1522139691342`
`1522139692342`, exactly a second.
         `^`

Answer (score 4):

The best precision you can possibly get is through the use of the x86-only "rdtsc" instruction, which can provide clock-level resolution (ne must of course take into account the cost of the rdtsc call itself, which can be measured easily on application startup).

The main catch here is measuring the number of clocks per second, which shouldn't be too hard.

Comment: You may also need to be concerned about processor affinity, because on some machines you might send the RDTSC calls to more than one processor and their RDTSC counters may not be synchronised.

Comment: And furthermore, some processors do not have a monotonically increasing TSC - think power-savings modes that reduce the CPU frequency. Using RDTSC for anything but *very* short localized timings is a **VERY** bad idea.

Comment: Btw, the core drift mentioned by @WillDean and using rdtsc for timing is the reason a number of games failed to work on (early?) multi-core AMD64 CPUs - I had to limit to single-core affinity on my x2 4400+ for a number of titles.

Answer (score 0):

**As of ANSI/ISO *C11 or later***, you can use `timespec_get()` to obtain millisecond, microsecond, or nanosecond timestamps, like this:

```c
#include <time.h>

/// Convert seconds to milliseconds
#define SEC_TO_MS(sec) ((sec)*1000)
/// Convert seconds to microseconds
#define SEC_TO_US(sec) ((sec)*1000000)
/// Convert seconds to nanoseconds
#define SEC_TO_NS(sec) ((sec)*1000000000)

/// Convert nanoseconds to seconds
#define NS_TO_SEC(ns)   ((ns)/1000000000)
/// Convert nanoseconds to milliseconds
#define NS_TO_MS(ns)    ((ns)/1000000)
/// Convert nanoseconds to microseconds
#define NS_TO_US(ns)    ((ns)/1000)

/// Get a time stamp in milliseconds.
uint64_t millis()
{
    struct timespec ts;
    timespec_get(&ts, TIME_UTC);
    uint64_t ms = SEC_TO_MS((uint64_t)ts.tv_sec) + NS_TO_MS((uint64_t)ts.tv_nsec);
    return ms;
}

/// Get a time stamp in microseconds.
uint64_t micros()
{
    struct timespec ts;
    timespec_get(&ts, TIME_UTC);
    uint64_t us = SEC_TO_US((uint64_t)ts.tv_sec) + NS_TO_US((uint64_t)ts.tv_nsec);
    return us;
}

/// Get a time stamp in nanoseconds.
uint64_t nanos()
{
    struct timespec ts;
    timespec_get(&ts, TIME_UTC);
    uint64_t ns = SEC_TO_NS((uint64_t)ts.tv_sec) + (uint64_t)ts.tv_nsec;
    return ns;
}

// NB: for all 3 timestamp functions above: gcc defines the type of the internal
// `tv_sec` seconds value inside the `struct timespec`, which is used
// internally in these functions, as a signed `long int`. For architectures
// where `long int` is 64 bits, that means it will have undefined
// (signed) overflow in 2^64 sec = 5.8455 x 10^11 years. For architectures
// where this type is 32 bits, it will occur in 2^32 sec = 136 years. If the
// implementation-defined epoch for the timespec is 1970, then your program
// could have undefined behavior signed time rollover in as little as
// 136 years - (year 2021 - year 1970) = 136 - 51 = 85 years. If the epoch
// was 1900 then it could be as short as 136 - (2021 - 1900) = 136 - 121 =
// 15 years. Hopefully your program won't need to run that long. :). To see,
// by inspection, what your system's epoch is, simply print out a timestamp and
// calculate how far back a timestamp of 0 would have occurred. Ex: convert
// the timestamp to years and subtract that number of years from the present
// year.
```

**For a *much-more-thorough* answer of mine, including with [an entire timing library](https://github.com/ElectricRCAircraftGuy/eRCaGuy_hello_world/blob/master/c/timinglib.h) I wrote, see here: [How to get a simple timestamp in C](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67731965/4561887).**

@Ciro Santilli Путлер also [presents a concise demo of C11's `timespec_get()` function here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36095514/4561887), which is how I first learned how to use that function.

In [my more-thorough answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67731965/4561887), I explain that on my system, the best resolution possible is **~20ns**, but the resolution is hardware-dependent and can vary from system to system.

Answer (score -4):

Under windows:

```
SYSTEMTIME t;
GetLocalTime(&t);
swprintf_s(buff, L"[%02d:%02d:%02d:%d]\t", t.wHour, t.wMinute, t.wSecond, t.wMilliseconds);
```

Comment: is this ansi C as per requested ?