# i need a real time clock in ansi c which provide an accuracy upto miliseconds?

Tags: c

i need a real time clock in ansi c which provide an accuracy upto miliseconds?

i am working on windows a windows base lib is also acceptable thanx in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to measure time in milliseconds using ANSI C?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/361363/how-to-measure-time-in-milliseconds-using-ansi-c)

Comment: Didn't know how to get hyperlink to work in comments or I would have placed my 'answer' here.

Comment: @Michael I voted to close; it does it automatically.

Comment: [Some markdown](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6407/allow-html-tags-in-comments/28523#28523 "but not much") tags are allowed in comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do it with portable code prior to C11.

Starting with C11, you can use `timespec_get`, which will *often* (but doesn't necessarily) provide a resolution of milliseconds or better. Starting from C23, you can call `timespec_getres` to find out the resolution provided.

Since you're using Windows, you need to start out aware that Windows isn't a real-time system, so nothing you do is really guaranteed to be accurate. That said, you can start with `timeBeginPeriod(1);` to set the multimedia timer resolution to 1 millisecond. You can then call `timeGetTime()` to retrieve the current time with 1 ms resolution. When you're done doing timing, you call `timeEndPeriod(1)` to set the timer resolution back to the default.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot be sure in ANSI C that the underlying system provides accuracy in milliseconds. However to achieve maximum detail you can use the `clock()` function which returns the time since process startup in ticks where the duration of a tick is defined by `CLOCKS_PER_SEC`:

```
#include <time.h>

double elapsed; // in milliseconds
clock_t start, end;

start = clock();

/* do some work */

end = clock();
elapsed = ((double) (end - start) * 1000) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
```

From GNU's [documentation](http://www.cs.utah.edu/dept/old/texinfo/glibc-manual-0.02/library_19.html#SEC310).

Comment: `clock()` returns processor time, not wall clock time.

Comment: I am aware of that. It is implied in my answer with "since process startup". The question does not make clear whether wall clock time is a requirement.

Answer (score 0):

The ANSI C clock() will give you **precision** of milliseconds, but not the accuracy, since that is dependent on window's system clock, which has accuracy to 50msec or somewhere around that range.  If you need something a little better, then you can use Windows API [QueryPerformanceCounter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644904%28VS.85%29.aspx), which has its own caveats as well.