# Using ANSI-C on Windows platform can I get time of system upto milliseconds accuracy?

Tags: c, windows, c89, high-resolution-clock

I need to get the millisecond accuracy. I take a look on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/361363/how-to-measure-time-in-milliseconds-using-ansi-c) but I am working on Windows: it gives linking errors for POSIX functions.

It will be very good if I can get UTC time since 1970 with milliseconds precision.

Comment: This is a really good question. You should restrict answers to providing at least millisecond resolution in the unix epoch using only ANSI-C or Windows API.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I get the Windows system time with millisecond resolution?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3729169/how-can-i-get-the-windows-system-time-with-millisecond-resolution)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not in ANSI C, but the Windows API provides a [`GetSystemTime`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/sysinfoapi/nf-sysinfoapi-getsystemtime) function as illustrated here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/minwinbase/ns-minwinbase-systemtime

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, but you can't do that using neither ANSI C nor the Windows API.

You *can* get the system time with a millisecond *resolution* using GetSystemTime or with a 100-nanosecond *resolution* using GetSystemTimeAsFileTime, but the *accuracy* will not be that good. The system time is only updated at each clock interval, which is somewhere around 10-15 milliseconds depending on the underlying architecture (SMP, Uniprocessor, ...).

There are ways to extrapolate the system time using different algorithms of varying complexity, but without the support of the operating system you'll never be guaranteed a correct high-resolution clock time.

Answer (score 0):

In Windows API there is a `SYSTEMTIME` structure and some system calls to get system time and local time of your machine, you can implement it in this way:

```
SYSTEMTIME systime;
GetSystemTime(&systime);
unsigned int millisec = systime.wMilliseconds;
```