# How to get the current time in milliseconds in C Programming

Tags: c, time.h

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to measure time in milliseconds using ANSI C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/361363/how-to-measure-time-in-milliseconds-using-ansi-c)
>   [How can I get the Windows system time with millisecond resolution?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3729169/how-can-i-get-the-windows-system-time-with-millisecond-resolution)

We want to calculate the time which a player have taken to finish the game.
But with time.h we could only calculate in seconds. but that is not exact. Is it possible to get the time in milliseconds? 
and what is the %? to printf?

Comment: exact dupilcate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/361363/how-to-measure-time-in-milliseconds-using-ansi-c

Answer (score 14, accepted):

quick answer

```
#include<stdio.h>   
#include<time.h>   

int main()   
{   
    clock_t t1, t2;  
    t1 = clock();   
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < 1000000; i++)   
    {   
        int x = 90;  
    }   

    t2 = clock();   

    float diff = ((float)(t2 - t1) / 1000000.0F ) * 1000;   
    printf("%f",diff);   

    return 0;   
}
```

Comment: I thought `clock` yields the cpu time used, not the real time.

Comment: This code, while possibly correct on some systems, will not always work.  You should use CLOCKS_PER_SEC rather than hard-code 1000000.

Comment: @jarmod nice pickup - its required especially on windows under MS VC++ where CLOCKS_PER_SEC is set to 1000.

Comment: Shouldn't the answer be changed according to @jarmod comment or at least remove this answer as a correct answer? (@Błażej Michalik)

Answer (score 20):

There is no portable way to get resolution of less than a second in standard C So best you can do is, use the POSIX function **[gettimeofday()](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/000095399/functions/gettimeofday.html)**.

Comment: On Windows, you could also GetTickCount ().

Answer (score 1):

If you're on a Unix-like system, use `gettimeofday` and convert the result from microseconds to milliseconds.