# Calculating function time in nanoseconds

Tags: c, windows, time, benchmarking, high-resolution-clock

I need to know how can I calculate the time of a function in C code in nanoseconds.

I tried to repeat the function until consume some microseconds. Are there any other functions in `time.h` that can be used to calculate the time in nanoseconds?

Comment: Accuracy to the nanosecond is at best highly platform dependent. What platform - Windows/Linux/something embedded?

Comment: No, and measuring a single function call isn't very useful anyways. You could use clock() though.

Comment: If you are using linux, Linux is not real time platform. and its scheduler scale is in milliseconds.

Comment: Try do a profiling on the program to get a relative time of each function.

Comment: C11 becomes available `timespec_get` will do it: http://stackoverflow.com/a/36095407/895245 linux version of this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16275444/how-to-print-time-difference-in-accuracy-of-milliseconds-and-nanoseconds

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I get the Windows system time with millisecond resolution?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3729169/how-can-i-get-the-windows-system-time-with-millisecond-resolution)

Answer (score 12):

You are never going to get nanosecond accuracy. Think about what you are asking: on a 1 GHz CPU 1 nanosecond is a clock cycle. No matter what you attempt to call, you will never get that kind of accuracy, you are better off sticking to microseconds. A similar question with many examples is here: [C++ Cross-Platform High-Resolution Timer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1487695/c-cross-platform-high-resolution-timer).

For c only: on windows you want to use the [QueryPerformanceCounter](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/172338). And here is more on [QPC](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms979201.aspx). [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1739259/how-to-use-queryperformancecounter) is a related question on how to use QueryPerformanceCounter.

Comment: timespec_get from C11 returns up to nanoseconds, rounded to the resolution of the implementation. check out http://stackoverflow.com/a/36095783/2680660

Comment: @efreet I didnt say that you couldnt get a nanosecond return value, I said that it wouldnt be accurate and therefore no more useful than a millisecond return value.

Answer (score 3):

Regardless of how you approach this or what type of system/OS you are using, you are getting an approximate answer at best, with considerable variance due to the nature of the problem.

Second, you need a system that supports this kind of call. It's pretty easy if you're using QNX Neutrino:

http://www.qnx.com/developers/docs/6.3.0SP3/neutrino/lib_ref/c/clock_gettime.html

```
/*
 * This program calculates the time required to
 * execute the program specified as its first argument.
 * The time is printed in seconds, on standard out.
 */
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

#define BILLION  1000000000L;

int main( int argc, char** argv )
  {
    struct timespec start, stop;
    double accum;

    if( clock_gettime( CLOCK_REALTIME, &start) == -1 ) {
      perror( "clock gettime" );
      return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    system( argv[1] );

    if( clock_gettime( CLOCK_REALTIME, &stop) == -1 ) {
      perror( "clock gettime" );
      return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    accum = ( stop.tv_sec - start.tv_sec )
             + (double)( stop.tv_nsec - start.tv_nsec )
               / (double)BILLION;
    printf( "%lf\n", accum );
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

The `clock` function in standard C is not useful for this. It usually has horrible resolution and it's inconsistent (between platforms) whether it measures elapsed wall time or cpu time consumed. You should use the POSIX-standard `clock_gettime` function (which has nanosecond resolution and lets you specify which clock you want to measure against) and emulate it with whatever system-specific clock operations are available on platforms that lack the POSIX function.

Comment: note: there is a difference between "nanosecond resolution" and "nanosecond accuracy". furthermore, he wants a windows solution, which this is not (sorry, he mentioned it in a comment, I just added the tag).

Answer (score 0):

Call the function enough times that you get total time in the seconds, and use any method to measure (even plain C clock()).  Measuring in micro/nanoseconds is inherently too imprecise.

For benchmarking, you want [QueryPerformanceCounter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644904%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).  It is the best stopwatch available on Windows.  See: [How to use QueryPerformanceCounter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1739259/how-to-use-queryperformancecounter)  However using this to measure (for example) a single function call will still be inherently very imprecise; I think you need to time on the order of a second total to get good signal-to-noise ratio for your measurements.  Take multiple measurements of whatever duration you want and compare their value to their standard deviation to make sure you are measuring sufficiently accurately.

[Multimedia Timers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd743609%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) are probably the best clock (note the difference between clock and stopwatch: one measures absolute time, the other time intervals only) available on Windows.  You should be able to get near-millisecond resolution and precision with [timeGetTime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd757629%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)().