# SDL_GetTicks() accuracy below the millisecond level

Tags: c++, sdl, sdl-2, timedelta

I program currently something with SDL2.
All works fine, but I have a problem with the `SDL_GetTicks()` method.
Normally it should return the total application time in milliseconds, but it always returns most of the time the value 0 and sometimes the value 1.

I initialized SDL with `SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING` flag.

The problem with the following code is the loop is too fast, so the delta time is smaller than 1 ms. Is there a method to achieve a higher precision?

```
#include "Application.hpp"

void Application::Initialize()
{
    int sdl_initialize_result = SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING);
    if(sdl_initialize_result < 0)
    {
        std::cerr << "Failed to initialize SDL !" << std::endl << SDL_GetError() << std::endl;
    }

    window = SDL_CreateWindow("Project Unknown", 100, 100, 800, 600, SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN);
    if(window == nullptr)
    {
        std::cerr << "Failed to create  SDL window !" << std::endl << SDL_GetError() << std::endl;
    }

    last_update_time = SDL_GetTicks();
}

void Application::Dispose()
{
    SDL_DestroyWindow(window);
    SDL_Quit();
}

void Application::Render()
{
}

void Application::Update()
{
    Uint32  current_time = SDL_GetTicks();
    Uint32  delta_time = current_time - last_update_time;


    SDL_Event event;
    while(SDL_PollEvent(&event))
    {
        switch(event.type)
        {
            case SDL_QUIT:
            {
                should_close = true;
            }
            break;

            default:
            {

            }
            break;
        }
    }

    // Update game objects with delta_time

    last_update_time = current_time;
}


void Application::Run()
{
    Initialize();

    should_close = false;
    do
    {
        Render();
        Update();
    }
    while(should_close == false);

    Dispose();
}
```

Comment: Some code could help us solve the problem.

Comment: and, which use it causing you problems? what type is last_update_time?

Comment: The problem is, that SDL_GetTicks() return values, that make no sense. Always 0 and sometimes 1. But in every documentation and tutorial this method should return the time in milliseconds since SDL was initialized.

Comment: try changing Uint32 to regular int. It works fine for me when just using int. Also, if you're compiling SDL2 for yourself, make sure there isn't a bug in the current commit.

Comment: I used a pre compiled stable build. And to change the type to int doesen't hepled :(

Comment: your question is entirely misleading. you state that the problem is with the return value of `SDL_GetTicks()`, but its clear from your edit that this is not the case. you should revise your question so it addresses the actual issue you are having.

Comment: .. I rephrased your title and question to state that the *current* shown code works "as designed" but you need a higher accuracy. Please check if this is indeed what you want to know.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16275444/how-to-print-time-difference-in-accuracy-of-milliseconds-and-nanoseconds

Comment: This is quite ridiculous. Many libraries use the highest resolution clock available, it should be a time returned as a double. On my PC I can get it through the Windows API, through the C++ std library, or any other number of ways, yet SDL which claims to be generalised cross-platform games media library can't handle this simple task, and returns a uint32 as milliseconds. Congratulations to them and to Steam who backed them.

Answer (score 8):

You cannot use SDL_GetTicks() if you want higher precision but there are many other alternatives. If you want to be platform independant you need to be careful though, but here is a portable C++11 example that will get you started:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>
typedef std::chrono::high_resolution_clock Clock;

int main()
{
    auto t1 = Clock::now();
    auto t2 = Clock::now();
    std::cout << "Delta t2-t1: " 
              << std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::nanoseconds>(t2 - t1).count()
              << " nanoseconds" << std::endl;
}
```

Running this on ideone.com gave me:

```
Delta t2-t1: 282 nanoseconds
```

Comment: Entirely compiler-and-OS-dependent. Will not work under GCC, windows, or MSVC 2013, for example.

Comment: It's not OS dependent, but yes you need a compiler capable of compiling C++11 which i guess you don't have.

Comment: It actually is OS-dependent, because different OS's have different internal counters, some better than others. None of the major compilers on Windows at this point have a functioning chrono which is capable of actual nanosecond timing.

Comment: `std::chrono::high_resolution_clock` is implementation-defined. Stick to `std::chrono::steady_clock`

Answer (score 3):

Well, of course, you need to actually wait until >=1ms has passed before updating your last tick count

```
void Application::Update()
{
    Uint32  current_time = SDL_GetTicks();
    Uint32  delta_time = current_time - last_update_time;

    SDL_Event event;
    while(SDL_PollEvent(&event))
    {
        switch(event.type)
        {
            case SDL_QUIT:
            {
                should_close = true;
            }
            break;

            default:
                break;
        }
    }

    if (delta_time >= 1)
    {
        // Update game objects with delta_time

        last_update_time = current_time;
    }   
}
```