# Only Evaluates as True when Thread Sleeps

Tags: c++, while-loop, boolean, double, game-loop

I am getting some unexpected behavior I don't understand. I am trying to implement a fixed variable time step as described from http://gafferongames.com/game-physics/fix-your-timestep/ and http://gameprogrammingpatterns.com/game-loop.html. My inner while loop never evaluates as true when I run the program in visual studio; however, when I uncomment 'this_thread::sleep_for(1s)', the while loop will evaluate as a true after the outer loop executes 10 times or so. I would expect on faster machines, this would be the expected outcome.

So my question is why would the inner loop only evaluate as true when the 'this_thread::sleep_for(1s)' is uncommented? Shouldn't lagTime become greater than fixedDeltaTime regardless of the sleep_for? Does the math take too much time for the computer or something?

```
int updateCount = 0;

double CLOCKS_PER_MILLISECOND((double)CLOCKS_PER_SEC * 1000.0);
double previousTime = std::clock() / CLOCKS_PER_MILLISECOND;
double newTime = 0, deltaTime = 0, lagTime = 0;
double fixedDeltaTime = 1.0 / 60.0;

while (gameIsRunning)
{
    newTime = std::clock() / CLOCKS_PER_MILLISECOND;
    deltaTime = newTime - previousTime;
    previousTime = newTime;
    lagTime += deltaTime;

    inputSystem.update();
    sceneManager.update();

    while(lagTime >= fixedDeltaTime) // never evalutes as true?
    {
        physicsSystem.update();

        lagTime -= fixedDeltaTime;

        updateCount++;
    }

    std::cerr << "-----" << updateCount << "-----" << std::endl;

    physicsSystem.interpolate(lagTime / fixedDeltaTime);

    renderSystem.update();
    audioSystem.update();

    updateCount = 0;
    //std::this_thread::sleep_for(1s);
}
```

Thank you for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're trying to measure time using `clock()`, but that is a process tick counter that won't advance while all threads in your process are sleeping. The whole point of `sleep` is to tell the CPU "don't give this process any attention for a while!". As far as your program is concerned, time freezes while it's asleep.

If you waited long enough, `lagTime` would eventually advance past `fixedDeltaTime` because the period of time during which your program is *not* sleeping consumes ticks ... but you'd have to wait for many, many seconds.

Don't use `clock()` to measure the absolute passage of time.

Comment: Thank you. I didn't realize that. I switched clock() to using the SDL function SDL_GetTicks() and that solved the issue.

Is there a c++ standard way to get absolute time? Thank you!

Comment: @leaflet757: Only if your compiler is new enough http://stackoverflow.com/a/26651148/560648