# Why does this elapsed time (frametime) calculation lockup my game

Tags: c++, loops, sdl

currently I am trying to implement a fixed-step game loop but somehow my code seems to lockup my game.

---

`Uint32 SDL_GetTicks(void)` : Returns an unsigned 32-bit value representing the number of milliseconds since the SDL library initialized.

This works:

1.cc)

```
Uint32 FPS = 60;
Uint32 MS_PER_SEC = 1000 / FPS;
Uint32 current_time, last_time, elapsed_time;
current_time = last_time = elapsed_time = 0;

while(Platform.Poll())
{
    current_time = SDL_GetTicks(); // Get time of frame begin

    // Clear Window
    Renderer.Clear();

    // Update Input
    //...

    // Draw
    Renderer.Draw();

    // Update Window
    Renderer.Update();

    last_time = SDL_GetTicks(); // Get time of frame end
    elapsed_time = last_time - current_time; // calculate frametime

    SDL_Delay(MS_PER_SEC - elapsed_time);
}
```

However this does not:

2.cc)

```
Uint32 FPS = 60;
Uint32 MS_PER_SEC = 1000 / FPS;
Uint32 current_time, last_time, elapsed_time;
current_time = elapsed_time = 0;

last_time = SDL_GetTicks();

// Poll for Input
while(Platform.Poll())
{
    current_time = SDL_GetTicks();
    elapsed_time = current_time - last_time;

    // Clear Window
    Renderer.Clear();

    // Update Input
    //...

    // Draw
    Renderer.Draw();

    // Update Window
    Renderer.Update();

    last_time = current_time;
    SDL_Delay(MS_PER_SEC - elapsed_time);
}
```

I expect the results of 1.cc and 2.cc to be the same, meaning that `SDL_Delay(MS_PER_SEC - elapsed_time)` does delay by a fixed time minus frametime (here 16 - frametime).
But 2.cc does lockup my game.

Is not the elapsed_time (frametime) calculation from 2.cc equivalent to 1.cc ?

Comment: Try printing out the delay amount to see if they are too long?

Comment: The delayed time's last value before lockup is ```18```, meaning 18ms, does not make sense to lockup.

edit: meant the delayed times value.

Comment: And what is the delay amount?

Comment: http://forums.libsdl.org/viewtopic.php?p=9050

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's unroll the loop a little...

```
// First iteration

last_time = SDL_GetTicks();
current_time = SDL_GetTicks();
elapsed_time = current_time - last_time; // Probably zero

...

SDL_Delay(MS_PER_SEC - elapsed_time);    // Probably a whole second

// Second iteration

current_time = SDL_GetTicks();
elapsed_time = current_time - last_time; // Probably slightly more than a whole second

...

SDL_Delay(MS_PER_SEC - elapsed_time);    // Probably negative (4 billion milliseconds)
```

Comment: You are right the delayed time accumulates to the value ```4294967293``` after some time. Seems like an overflow.

Answer (score 0):

That function  is based on RTC and have very low accuracy and and uses much time to use, depending on platform. 10-30 milliseocnds accuracy is an optimistic guess.

This might be related: [SDL_GetTicks() accuracy below the millisecond level](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26440860/sdl-getticks-accuracy-below-the-millisecond-level)