# CLOCK_REALTIME nanosecond precision support in kernel

Tags: c, linux

I wrote a simple program to determine if i can get nanosecond precision on my system, which is a RHEL 5.5 VM (kernel 2.6.18-194).

```c
// cc -g -Wall ntime.c -o ntime -lrt
#include <inttypes.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])  {
    struct timespec spec;

    printf("CLOCK_REALTIME - \"Systemwide realtime clock.\":\n");
    clock_getres(CLOCK_REALTIME, &spec);
    printf("\tprecision: %ldns\n", spec.tv_nsec);
    clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &spec);
    printf("\tvalue    : %010ld.%-ld\n", spec.tv_sec, spec.tv_nsec);

    printf("CLOCK_MONOTONIC - \"Represents monotonic time. Cannot be set.\":\n");
    clock_getres(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &spec);
    printf("\tprecision: %ldns\n", spec.tv_nsec);
    clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &spec);
    printf("\tvalue    : %010ld.%-ld\n", spec.tv_sec, spec.tv_nsec);

    return 0;
}
```

A sample output:

```
CLOCK_REALTIME - "Systemwide realtime clock.":
        precision: 999848ns
        value    : 1504781052.328111000
CLOCK_MONOTONIC - "Represents monotonic time. Cannot be set.":
        precision: 999848ns
        value    : 0026159205.299686941
```

So `REALTIME` gives me the local time and `MONOTONIC` the system's uptime. Both clocks seem to have a μs precision (999848ns ≅ 1ms), even though `MONOTONIC` outputs in nanoseconds, which is confusing.

`man clock_gettime` states:

> CLOCK_REALTIME_HR
>         High resolution version of CLOCK_REALTIME.

However, `grep -R CLOCK_REALTIME_HR /usr/include/ | wc -l` returns `0` and trying to compile results in `error: ‘CLOCK_REALTIME_HR’ undeclared (first use in this function)`.

I was trying to determine if i could get the local time in nanosecond precision, but either my code has a bug or maybe this feature isn't entirely supported in 5.5 (or the VM's HPET is off, or something else).

*Can* i get local time in nanoseconds in this system? What am i doing wrong?

*EDIT*

Well the answer seems to be No.

While nanosecond precision can be achieved, the system doesn't guarantee nanosecond accuracy in this scenario (here's a clear [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16740505/1831722) on the difference rather than a rant). Typical COTS hardware doesn't really handle it (another [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16276032/1831722) in the right direction).

I'm still curious as to why do the clocks report the same `clock_getres` resolution yet `MONOTONIC` yields what seems to be nanosecond values while `REALTIME` yields microseconds.

Comment: You hardly get microsecond precision in Linux, definitively not nanoseconds! Maybe you confuse precision and resolution? **Very** different things! And that smells strongly like an XY problem. Why do you want to get ns resolution at all?

Comment: Precision is easy, accuracy is not.

Comment: 'Can i get local time in nanoseconds in this system?' Where in the system?  Moving such a value about, (eg. returning it from a kernel call), would render it stale.

Comment: @Olaf i was checking if a business requirement could be met (without delving into hard real time systems) and surpassed. Timestamping etc.

Comment: @MartinJames point taken. In this case, as long as the time delay is the same, there shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: Does anyone know when did the kernel start to support nanosecond precision? And/Or is this distro-related?

Comment: Your question still does not make any sense. Did you even read my comment completely? Did you understand the differences? Did you use a proper translation tool? If you need ns **precision**, no current realtime system will guarantee this. even a hardware implementation in an FPGA would have to struggle hard, depoending on the actual problem.

Comment: 999848ns is about 1 millisecond (msec), not 1 microsecond (μsec).

Comment: @stark corrected, thanks

Answer (score 0):

RHEL5 is really ancient at this point, you should consider upgrading. On a newer system (Ubuntu 16.04) your program produces:

```
CLOCK_REALTIME - "Systemwide realtime clock.":
    precision: 1ns
    value    : 1504783164.686220185
CLOCK_MONOTONIC - "Represents monotonic time. Cannot be set.":
    precision: 1ns
    value    : 0000537257.257923964
```

Comment: Clock resolution depends on the hardware.  These days, frequently a timer in the CPU.