# Program execution time in accuracy better than ms

Tags: c, time

I am using `time_taken = ((double)t * 1000) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;`
Where

```
    t = clock();
    myFunctionToMeasureTimeTaken();
    t = clock() - t;
```

But at best it only give the running time in ms. And that function runs way too fast.

Is there anything I can use to measure in times of micro or even nanosec?

I am using MS Visual Studio 2013

Comment: You could try a [high resolution timer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644900(v=vs.85).aspx#high_resolution), though it's not portable. Or you could run the function a 1000 times and measure the average run-time instead.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13610471/calculating-function-time-in-nanoseconds-in-c-code

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to print time difference in accuracy of milliseconds and nanoseconds?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16275444/how-to-print-time-difference-in-accuracy-of-milliseconds-and-nanoseconds)

Answer (score 0):

The usual way to time functions with short execution times, when only a coarse timer is available, is to run the function repeatedly in a loop, say, a million times, and measure that.

If you are willing to sacrifice Standard C conformance, there may be system specific timers with higher resolution.