# How to change the format of date and time with time_t?

Tags: c++, date, time, formatting, time-t

```
time_t now = time(0);  
std::string h = std::string (ctime (&now));

std::cout << "\nh: " << h;
```

Current output that I am receiving is: `Thu Sep 14 10:58:26 2017`

I want the output as `2017-08-26-16-10-56`

What can I do to that output?

Comment: Related question : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3673226/how-to-print-time-in-format-2009-08-10-181754-811

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [strftime](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ctime/strftime/), like this:

```
strftime (buffer, 80,"%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M-%S",timeinfo);
```

---

Full code:

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <ctime>

int main ()
{
  time_t rawtime;
  struct tm * timeinfo;
  char buffer [80];

  time (&rawtime);
  timeinfo = localtime (&rawtime);

  strftime (buffer, 80,"%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M-%S",timeinfo);
  puts (buffer);

  return 0;
}
```

Output:

> 2017-09-14-14-41-19

Answer (score 4):

Use [`std::put_time`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/put_time)

```
#include <iomanip>

time_t now = time(0);
std::string h = std::put_time(localtime(&now), "%F-%H-%M-%S");
std::cout << "\nh: " << h;
```

Output

> h: 2017-09-14-05-54-02

Even better, use `std::chrono`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <chrono>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    auto now = chrono::system_clock::to_time_t(chrono::system_clock::now());
    cout << put_time(localtime(&now), "%F-%H-%M-%S") << endl;
    return 0;
}
```