# C - can I output formatted time to text file

Tags: c, time, file-io

I want to output time to a text file, and the time should be formatted as (dd-mm-yy). I've referred to [How to print time in format: 2009‐08‐10 18:17:54.811](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3673226/how-to-print-time-in-format-2009-08-10-181754-811) (using code from top answer) and I am now stuck with this piece of code:

```
int main()
{
    time_t timer;
    char buffer[26], line[50]; // Hoping to feed in date and time into a string (line[50])
    struct tm* tm_info;

    time(&timer);
    tm_info = localtime(&timer);

    strftime(buffer, 26, "%d-%m-%y %H:%M:%S", tm_info);
    puts(buffer);


    return 0;
}
```

Which give mes an output of the current local time and date in the format (dd-mm-yy) and (hh-mm-ss) on stdout. So now I'm just wondering if I can feed this format into a text file as well.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: So your actual question is "How can I write text into a file rather than on the screen", right? Please confirm.

Comment: Yes. I'm stuck at assignment so I can't really go through with writing the time into the file yet.

Comment: It's `int main(void)` and your code does not compile.

Comment: Next time when you ask a question please focus on your actual problem, time functions and other time related questions are not related to your problem, so you should not have mentioned them.

Comment: Look into [`fopen`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fopen/) and [`fputs`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fputs/) and read the chapter dealing with files in your C text book.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `fopen`,`fclose` and `fputs` to write to a file.

For more info
read [fopen](https://linux.die.net/man/3/fopen).
[fclose](https://linux.die.net/man/3/fclose).
[fputs](https://linux.die.net/man/3/fputs).

**Example:**

```
FILE *fp = fopen("time.txt", "w");
if (fp == NULL) return 1;
fputs(buffer, fp);
fclose(fp);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the `fputs` function. Add this code after your `puts(buffer)` line.

```
FILE* file = fopen("yourtextfile.txt","w");
if (file != NULL){
    fputs(buffer,file);
    fclose(file);
}
```

The second parameter in `fopen`should be changed according to your needs: `"w"` will erase what was previously written in the file, `"a"` will append (write at the end of your file). In both cases, the file will be created if it doesn't exist.