# How to change the output of my time_t function in c++?

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-c++, c++14, c++17

Currently the function

```
    time_t now1 = time(0);
    CString AuditDate1 = ctime(&now1);
```

Exports the time to the database as

Day Mon DD HH:MM:SS YYYY
For Example: Tue Jul 28 14:22:01 2020

I need the time to be outputted as

YYYY.MM.DD HH:MM:SS

I don't even need the time, more importantly the date. The time is a bonus.

Your help is much appreciated!

Comment: Your tags are crazy. Which version of C++ do you target ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3673226/how-to-print-time-in-format-2009-08-10-181754-811  (you're using C API so the dupe is for C too)

Comment: Yes it does rustyx! Feel free to make it an answer and I will upvote it!