# How to get milliseconds with the date and time using Lua script

Tags: datetime, lua

I am trying to get milliseconds with the Lua date time
This is how I am getting os time.

```
time = os.date("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
```

which returns me the date and time as **2022-08-15 08:30:40** I also want to add milliseconds(00 to 999) with it like the expected output is **2022-08-15 08:30:40.786**

I tried to find it but had no success even here at Lua date time page there is no info about this https://www.lua.org/pil/22.1.html

Any help would be appreciated, Thanks

Comment: It is impossible: `os.date` internally invokes C function `strftime` which knows only integer amount of seconds.  See the most upvoted comment under [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3673305/1847592) for a "workaround" :-)

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff Thanks for comment, can you help me with this how can i format this `239657|20220815T082447.275Z` to date and time in lua? here after the symbol **|** is the date and time. can i get it  as `2022-08-08 08:24:47.275`.
Help would be appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Do you want just to beautify the string (insert dashes and colons)?  Or do you want to pass it as time argument to `os.date()`?  `os.date` accepts integer amount of seconds since 1970, so `.275` should be thrown away.

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff I just want dashes, like out put should be `2022-08-08 08:24:47.275` , no need for the datetime, need to beautify the string.

Comment: `str = str:match"|(.*)":gsub("^(%d%d%d%d)(%d%d)(%d%d)T(%d%d)(%d%d)(%d%d%.%d*)Z", "%1-%2-%3 %4:%5:%6")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is impossible to get sub-second time resolution by using `os.date`.
`os.date` internally invokes C function `strftime` which does not have fractional seconds data field in the data structure it's working with.