# How to get the current time in milliseconds from C in Linux?

Tags: c, linux, posix

How do I get the current time on Linux in milliseconds?

Answer (score 132):

This can be achieved using the [POSIX `clock_gettime`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/clock_gettime.html) function.

In the current version of POSIX, `gettimeofday` is [marked obsolete](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/gettimeofday.html#tag_16_222_07). This means it may be removed from a future version of the specification. Application writers are encouraged to use the `clock_gettime` function instead of `gettimeofday`.

Here is an example of how to use `clock_gettime`:

```
#define _POSIX_C_SOURCE 200809L

#include <inttypes.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

void print_current_time_with_ms (void)
{
    long            ms; // Milliseconds
    time_t          s;  // Seconds
    struct timespec spec;

    clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &spec);

    s  = spec.tv_sec;
    ms = round(spec.tv_nsec / 1.0e6); // Convert nanoseconds to milliseconds
    if (ms > 999) {
        s++;
        ms = 0;
    }

    printf("Current time: %"PRIdMAX".%03ld seconds since the Epoch\n",
           (intmax_t)s, ms);
}
```

If your goal is to measure elapsed time, and your system supports the "monotonic clock" option, then you should consider using `CLOCK_MONOTONIC` instead of `CLOCK_REALTIME`.

Comment: +1 for being POSIXly correct — but your answer has the wrong units.  The OP doesn't want the time _with_ milliseconds, but the time _in_ milliseconds.

Comment: Good solution but don't forget the _-lm_ in your `gcc` command.

Comment: according to the manpage for round, you want to use lround when assigning the result to an integer (or long)

Comment: @hildred That's a good point, but in this case using `round` is safe and will always give an equivalent value to `lround`. That's because `tv_nsec` is itself a long, so the result of `round(spec.tv_nsec / 1.0e6)` can never be anything that won't correctly convert to a `long`. It will never try to round NaN or infinity and the result will always,  by definition, be within range of `long`.

Comment: You need to use floor() instead of round() so that it never rounds up to 1000 ms. Otherwise you would need to increment `s` when this happens. Probably a rare event but the extra digit can cause trouble.

Comment: @Mike Nice catch. At one in two thousand, it's not even that rare, so should definitely be fixed. Rather than use floor, I think I'd prefer to maintain a little more accuracy and continue to round, but increment the second counter if it rounds up to 1000.

Comment: An improvement to this would be to add to `s` to reflect how many seconds have passed. Something like: `remainder = ms % 1000; s += ((ms - remainder) / 1000) - 1; ms = remainder`. Otherwise you lose any extra seconds and milliseconds.

Comment: @SamTebbs33 there should never be any extra milliseconds. `spec.tv_nsec` will always be less than 1 billion (and hence ms will never be more than 1000 after rounding).

Answer (score 71):

You have to do something like this:

```
struct timeval  tv;
gettimeofday(&tv, NULL);

double time_in_mill = 
         (tv.tv_sec) * 1000 + (tv.tv_usec) / 1000 ; // convert tv_sec & tv_usec to millisecond
```

Answer (score 39):

Following is the util function to get current timestamp in milliseconds:

```
#include <sys/time.h>

long long current_timestamp() {
    struct timeval te; 
    gettimeofday(&te, NULL); // get current time
    long long milliseconds = te.tv_sec*1000LL + te.tv_usec/1000; // calculate milliseconds
    // printf("milliseconds: %lld\n", milliseconds);
    return milliseconds;
}
```

**About timezone**:

> **gettimeofday()** support to specify timezone,
>   I use **NULL**, which ignore the timezone, but you can specify a timezone, if need.

---

**@Update - timezone**

Since the `long` representation of time is not relevant to or effected by timezone itself, so setting `tz` param of gettimeofday() is not necessary, since it won't make any difference.

And, according to *man* page of `gettimeofday()`, the use of the `timezone` structure is obsolete, thus the `tz` argument should normally be specified as NULL, for details please check the man page.

Comment: > gettimeofday() support to specify timezone, I use NULL, which ignore the timezone, but you can specify a timezone, if need.

You are wrong. Time zone should be introduced exclusively via call to localtime().

Comment: @vitaly.v.ch I did a test, passing the `tz` param of `gettimeofday()` as `&(struct timezone tz = {480, 0})` won't get any warning, and it don't have any effect to the result, that makes sense, since the `long` representation of time is not relevant to or effected by timezone itself, right?

Comment: There was no reason to do any test. Linux kernel does not have proper information about time-zones, and at the same time does not have a way to provide it. It a reason why tz argument is processed in very specific way. long representation does not matter.

Comment: @vitaly.v.ch At a specific time point, long representation don't varies due to timezone, that's why it matters, and due to that normally only `NULL` is the reasonable value to pass. And, I believe testing is always a good approach to prove things.

Answer (score 13):

Use [`gettimeofday()`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/gettimeofday) to get the time in seconds and microseconds. Combining and rounding to milliseconds is left as an exercise.

Answer (score 8):

**C11 `timespec_get`**

It returns up to nanoseconds, rounded to the resolution of the implementation.

It is already implemented in Ubuntu 15.10. API looks the same as the POSIX `clock_gettime`.

```
#include <time.h>
struct timespec ts;
timespec_get(&ts, TIME_UTC);
struct timespec {
    time_t   tv_sec;        /* seconds */
    long     tv_nsec;       /* nanoseconds */
};
```

More details here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36095407/895245

Answer (score 4):

Derived from Dan Moulding's POSIX answer, this should work :

```
#include <time.h>
#include <math.h>

long millis(){
    struct timespec _t;
    clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &_t);
    return _t.tv_sec*1000 + lround(_t.tv_nsec/1e6);
}
```

Also as pointed out by David Guyon: compile with -lm

Comment: There is no need to invoke floating point. Just add 500K and integer divide by 1M.

Comment: Thanks for a tip, fixed my answer.

Answer (score 3):

This version need not math library and checked the return value of clock_gettime().

```c
#include <time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>

/**
 * @return milliseconds
 */
uint64_t get_now_time() {
  struct timespec spec;
  if (clock_gettime(1, &spec) == -1) { /* 1 is CLOCK_MONOTONIC */
    abort();
  }

  return spec.tv_sec * 1000 + spec.tv_nsec / 1e6;
}
```

Comment: Please state what your answer brings over the 6 other answers (in particular, given that 2 other answers already rely on `clock_gettime`), add which headers it requires, and in what way it addresses the OP's question. Concerning `CLOCK_MONOTONIC`, I would also recommend using standard macros directly in your answers (and in your code, in general) instead of literals.

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Comment: Dividing by the double (1e6) is unnecessary, bad form, and may introduce rounding errors on conversion.

Answer (score 2):

Jirka Justra's answer returns a long, which is usually 32 bits. The number of milliseconds since unix time 0 in 1970 requires more bits, so the data type
should be long long or unsigned long long, which is usually 64 bits. Also, as Kevin Thibedeau commented, rounding can be done without converting to floating point or using math.h.

```
#include <time.h>
long long millis () {
  struct timespec t ;
  clock_gettime ( CLOCK_REALTIME , & t ) ;
  return t.tv_sec * 1000 + ( t.tv_nsec + 500000 ) / 1000000 ;
}
```

If you are trying to measure time less than 50 days, 32 bits is enough. Data type int is 32 bits or 64 bits on most computers, so the data type can be unsigned int.

Comment: We generally want to represent time since the epoch (~50+ years ago), but a simple 64bit SIGNED int can represent +/- ~300million years from the epoch in milliseconds.  int64_t is  the correct type, NOT long long which may be 128bit.