# Highly accurate time measurement in C

Tags: c, linux

I'm trying to figure out a way to write some code that could accurately figure out the time required to perform a search on a BST. Currently im using time and the total number of elements is of the order 10^5. It looks something like the following :-

```
clock_t begin, end;
begin = clock();
...
...
...
end = clock();
difference = (end-begin)/CLOCKS_PER_SECOND;
```

However, this does not give me the precision that I'm looking for. Are there any other libc functions that I could use?

Comment: I think read: `difftime(,)`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Getting the current time in milliseconds](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3756323/getting-the-current-time-in-milliseconds)

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6749621/high-resolution-timer-in-linux and lots of other questions here

Answer (score 4):

If your library supports it, C11 has `timespec_get()` which will measure up to nanoseconds, depending on your system clock resolution.

Answer (score 2):

To benchmark your algorithm, you need to do some repetitions to get into the range of at least hundreds of milliseconds. (This is standard practice). To benchmark an algorithm that happens in user space only (no threading, system calls etc), you'd want to use `getrusage(RUSAGE_SELF, &r)` and use `r.ru_utime` value that contains seconds and microseconds.

Answer (score 2):

If you are running the benchmark with an Intel CPU. Maybe you can give a try to the RDTSC and RDTSCP instructions.

[here is a document about the instructions](http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/intelligent-systems/embedded-systems-training/ia-32-ia-64-benchmark-code-execution-paper.html)

Answer (score 0):

BST? What kind of precision do you want? Dividing by CLOCKS_PER_SECOND being 10^6 on a 32-bit system should give a 6-digit precision?

Do you cast the result tot a double?

try

```
difference = (double)(end-begin)/CLOCKS_PER_SECOND;
```

Note that difference should be able to hold a double.

Comment: `clock()` is precise, but it isn't very accurate. It's usually only accurate to about 50 milliseconds. And on Linux, it also measures CPU-time instead of wall-time.

Comment: Yes I did use a double -- I got an output similar to 0.000000

Comment: @Mysticial Isn't CPU time what's needed here? The time it takes to search the BST shouldn't include the consumed time by other processes, which is what wall time would get you.

Comment: @NikosC. You shouldn't be benchmarking with other active processes anyway. CPU-time isn't an accurate measurement of performance anyway - especially with hyper-threading and turbo-boost and stuff. Not to mention shared caches and other resource contention.

Comment: @uki If you have 0.000000 you should check if the end and begin variables even contain any value with a debugger (or just output the to the console output or so).

Answer (score 0):

Qt has `QElapsedTimer` which supports measuring up to nanoseconds. I cannot testify to how accurate it is, IIRC it uses different implementations on different platforms. Sadly it is C++, which may not suit you. Also:

> On platforms that do not provide nanosecond resolution, the value
>   returned will be the best estimate available.

The `clock()` function is alright for rough measurements, but it works in the millisecond range. Contrary to its name, I don't think it measures in CPU clocks, since modern processors clock frequencies can vary quite a bit, making it impossible to determine the actual time accurately solely relying on CPU clocks. IMO this concept dates back to the days when CPU frequencies were constant, there was no power management, no "turbo boost" automatic overclocking or whatsoever.

EDIT: Also found this (time.h):

```
    int clock_gettime(clockid_t clk_id, struct timespec *tp);

    ... and the target struct...

    struct timespec {
            time_t   tv_sec;        /* seconds */
            long     tv_nsec;       /* nanoseconds */
    };

... and the clock options...


CLOCK_REALTIME
    System-wide realtime clock. Setting this clock requires appropriate privileges. 
CLOCK_MONOTONIC
    Clock that cannot be set and represents monotonic time since some unspecified starting point. 
CLOCK_PROCESS_CPUTIME_ID
    High-resolution per-process timer from the CPU. 
CLOCK_THREAD_CPUTIME_ID
    Thread-specific CPU-time clock.
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing is quite similar to what I've been recently doing.

I do think the `int gettimeofday(struct timeval *tv, struct timezone *tz);` function suits your need. The time info would be put into the `struct timeval  tv`, which gets the time in seconds and microseconds. The `struct timeval` from the man page:

```
struct timeval {
               time_t      tv_sec;     /* seconds */
               suseconds_t tv_usec;    /* microseconds */
};
```

A short example for time measurement with `gettimeofday`:

```
struct timeval time;
if(gettimeofday( &time, 0 )) return -1;

long cur_time = 1000000 * time.tv_sec + time.tv_usec;
double sec = cur_time / 1000000.0;
```

A longer example have been simplified and easily wrapped as a c++ class for convenient use. The code has been put on my github: https://github.com/lulyon/LinuxTimeCounter, which is use in a real world project.