# Measuring the exact run time in C

Tags: c, runtime, measure

I have an assignment that asks me to measure the exact run time of a couple of programs.  I am not sure how to do this, but I think it has something to do with time_start(); as I've seen this on the internet.  What does time_start(); mean, and how do I use it to measure run time?  I'm using Windows 7, and Dev C++ Compiler

Thank you

Comment: Presumably whoever set the assignment gave you this information...

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5248915/execution-time-of-c-program

Also, Google and StackOverflow are your friends. ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Precise" time measurement requires to use operating system specific functions.

Under Windows, you proably want to use the following function: ([MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644904%28v=vs.85%29.aspx))

```
BOOL WINAPI QueryPerformanceCounter(_Out_  LARGE_INTEGER *lpPerformanceCount);
```

This function gives you a high-resolution counter of ticks since your application started. The interval between two ticks depends on your processor and might be retrieved using the following function: ([MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644905%28v=vs.85%29.aspx))

```
BOOL WINAPI QueryPerformanceFrequency(_Out_  LARGE_INTEGER *lpFrequency);
```

So here is a snippet of code to get a precise value of the current time in seconds:

```
double GetCurTime()
{
    LARGE_INTEGER CounterFreq;
    QueryPerformanceFrequency(&CounterFreq);

    LARGE_INTEGER Counter;
    QueryPerformanceCounter(&Counter);
    return (double)Counter.QuadPart / (double)CounterFreq.QuadPart;
}
```

So to make a time measurement, call `GetCurTime()` at the beginning and call it again at the end, and take the difference between the two values.

Comment: Also note that you could retrieve the `PerformanceFrequency` at the beginning of your program and store the value, since it never changes during the execution. So you can reduce this function to a single system call instead of two.