# Discrepancy between “time ./main” in terminal vs. <time.h>

Tags: c, time

After compiling my code in C, I use “time ./main” from the terminal (Mac OS X) and get

```
real    0m0.004s
user    0m0.001s
sys     0m0.002s
```

But using `<time.h>` as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5248915/execution-time-of-c-program), I get an elapsed time of `0.000217` seconds. So I’m just wondering how these two measurements differ.

Comment: On current hardware and operating system such a small time is not significant. You practically need to change your program (or its invocation) to have a time of a few seconds (or at least half of a second), and you need to repeat the benchmark several times.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`time ./exe` will measure more things - loading the exe, starting the program, finishing the program, etc. These are a lot of things, especially of there are loading of dynamic libraries and things like this.

Using `time.h` you can measure the time from line `x` to line `y` - this will *not* include anything else (like startup time, etc.)

Also note @BasileStarynkevitch 's comment under the question.