# Why is a loop in `else if(!var)` faster than one in `else`?

Tags: c++, loops, for-loop

I have two blocks which do the same thing.

```
if(print) for(int i = 0; i < numt; i++) if(primes[i]) {
    printf("%d\n", i);
    numprimes++;
}
    //fast
else if(!print) for(int i = 0; i < numt; i++) if(primes[i]) {
    numprimes++;
}
```

and

```
if(print) for(int i = 0; i < numt; i++) if(primes[i]) {
    printf("%d\n", i);
    numprimes++;
}
    //very slow
else for(int i = 0; i < numt; i++) if(primes[i]) {
    numprimes++;
}
```

I estimate that the first one is a hundered times faster than the second one. Why is this? The effect occurs in multiple compilers (Mingw, msvc). `print` is false by default, but you can change it with the command line args. I ran the program without any in both cases. This is a real mystery...

disassembly:
[block 1](http://onlinedisassembler.com/odaweb/B9GEai)
[block 2](http://onlinedisassembler.com/odaweb/JhcGlR)

whole file:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    int numt = 1000000;
    int sqrtt = sqrt(numt);
    bool* primes = malloc(numt*sizeof(int));
    int numprimes = 0;
    bool print = true;
    time_t start, end;


    if(argc > 2) if(!strcmp(argv[2], "-np")) print = false;
    if(argc > 1) sscanf(argv[1], "%d", &numt);


    if(primes == NULL) {
        printf("error in allocation");
        return 1;
    }

    memset(primes, true, numt);

    primes[0] = false;
    primes[1] = false;

    for(long long id = 1; id <= sqrtt; id++) if(primes[id]) for(long long cl = id*id; cl <= numt; cl+= id) primes[cl] = false;

    start = clock();
    //start block
    if(print) for(int i = 0; i < numt; i++) if(primes[i]) {
        printf("%d\n", i);
        numprimes++;
    }
    else for(int i = 0; i < numt; i++) if(primes[i]) { //diff line
        numprimes++;
    }
    //end block

    end = clock();

    free(primes);

    printf("%d Primes before %d took %d", numprimes, numt, end-start);

    return 0;
}
```

exe fast: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B8ujl0shCPcHRTRENzFyeHpkd0U/edit?usp=sharing

exe slow: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B8ujl0shCPcHcmZQNDlLLTZ3OWM/edit?usp=sharing

video demo: http://youtu.be/45L4qkaPDmE

here is a c++ version to compare:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <math.h>
#include <ctime>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <omp.h>
#include <thread>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{

    const double s = GetTickCount();
    long long numt; //max number to compute to
    if(argc < 2) {
        cout << "Usage: "<<argv[0]<<" <primes until...>" << endl;
        return 1;
    }

    else if(atoi(argv[1])<1) {
        cout << "Usage: "<<argv[0]<<" <primes until...>" << endl;
        return 1;
    }
    numt = atol(argv[1])+1;

    bool skipprint = false;

    if(argc >=3) if(!strcmp(argv[2], "noprint")) skipprint = true;

    vector<bool> primes(numt); 

    primes.assign(numt, true); 

    primes[0] = false; //0 is not prime
    primes[1] = false; //1 is also not prime but we do not want to eliminate all multiples of 1 (all numbers)
    //#pragma omp parallel
    {
        const long long sqrtt = sqrt(numt); //don't need to go past sqrt(n) to eliminate all composites

        //#pragma omp parallel for
        for(long long id = 1; id <= sqrtt; id++) {
            if(primes[id]) {
                //#pragma omp for
                for(long long cl = id*id; cl <= numt; cl+= id) primes[cl] = false;
            }
        }

            //#pragma omp parallel for
            //for(long long cl = l*l; cl <= numt; cl+= l) primes[cl] = false;
    }
    const double m = GetTickCount();
    unsigned long long count = 0;




    //this is the block
    if(!skipprint) for(long long l = 2; l<numt; l++) if(primes[l]) {
        cout << l << endl;
        count ++;
    }
    if(skipprint) for(long long l = 2; l<numt; l++) if(primes[l]) count ++;
    //this is the end of the block




    const double e = GetTickCount();
    cout << endl;
    cout << count << " primes less than or equal to " << numt-1 << endl;
    cout << "Calculation took " << m-s << " ms";
    if(!skipprint) cout << " and printing took " << e-m << " ms";
    else cout << " and counting took " << e-m << " ms";
    cout <<"." << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: That is a weird indentation style.

Comment: how so @self? It seems quite normal to me. Or is it the comments?

Comment: `else if(!print) for(int i = 0; i < numt; i++) if(primes[i]) {` ?

Comment: That's normal @self. I use it all the time.

Comment: How did you estimate the time it took to execute a function?

Comment: estimate what? @staticx

Comment: @nimsson: " estimate that the first one is a hundered times faster than the second one."

Comment: I agree with @self - I have never seen that formatting style.

Comment: the speed that it printed the values @staticx. I have a sense of time, too.

Comment: @nimsson: That's not accurate. You need to actually measure it via CPU cycles.

Comment: Use this and report back: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5249150/2591612

Comment: Test code and compiler settings or it didn't happen.  And yeah, your formatting style is incredibly difficult to read.

Comment: can you just diff the disassembly and post the diff here? that way we could actually see whats happenning

Comment: @staticx the second one is so slow, I've run the second one several times since I started the first. It only seems to happen when numt = 1000000. It outputs about 10 terms a second vs the first one about a thousand terms a second.

Comment: ok @SteveCox I will post the disassembly shortly.

Comment: What compiler settings were you using? I just checked the assembly generated and the only difference was (surprise) an extra `cmp ..., 0` then `jne ...`

Comment: @matt -oprimes -O3 -Wall -std=c99

Comment: @nimsson: I'm not trying to insult your impression of time, but you really need to do clock it the way I showed you.

Comment: With those compiler settings (gcc 4.7.2, linux x64) I get exactly the same disassembly with [this code](http://pad.mattdiesel.co.uk/primes-test-disasm)

Comment: Assembly [test1](http://pastie.org/9073296) and [test2](http://pastie.org/9073297) for the code linked to above.

Comment: @Matt why wouldnt you post the diff?

Comment: Sure, it's pretty short... [diff](http://pastie.org/9073303)

Comment: @Matt see my full file at the end of the post. numt MUST be 1000000 to produce the effects.

Comment: Let me take a notice on your edit: An online disassembler exists!?! Now that's just way too cool!

Comment: @nimsson again, why not post the diff? reading through hundreds of lines of assembly in separate tabs isnt fun

Comment: getting the diffs right now @SteveCox

Comment: Diff from me compiling the full code in the op, with mingw32 and same flags as mentioned above: [here](http://pastie.org/9073317)

Comment: I can paste both exes @Matt.

Comment: I pasted my exes @Matt.

Comment: Blastfurnace's answer is correct below, but for future reference, you can compile with `-S -masm=intel` to output the assembly from gcc. It's a very useful thing to know.

Comment: @matt if you want a live demo, I posted one at http://youtu.be/45L4qkaPDmE

Answer (score 10, accepted):

*A well-intentioned edit to the posted code obscured the real problem.*

The original code was:

```
if(print) for(int i = 0; i < numt; i++) if(primes[i]) {
    printf("%d\n", i);
    numprimes++;
}
    //fast
else if(!print) for(int i = 0; i < numt; i++) if(primes[i]) {
    numprimes++;
}
```

and

```
if(print) for(int i = 0; i < numt; i++) if(primes[i]) {
    printf("%d\n", i);
    numprimes++;
}
    //very slow
else for(int i = 0; i < numt; i++) if(primes[i]) {
    numprimes++;
}
```

Notice how the last `else if(!print)` and `else for()` in the original code snippets bind to the previous `if(primes[i])`, not the initial `if(print)` test. **The edit added curly brackets that weren't in the original code and changed its behavior.**

Without curly brackets the two code snippets do different things and therefore the performance can't be compared. *I think nimsson's unusual coding style caused the problem.*

Comment: yep, there's a numt^2 slowdown there. looks about right

Comment: This is why you run code through a formatter before reading, would have made it very clear: [formatted version](http://pastie.org/9073336)

Comment: +1 for digging trough the revisions. Also the reason you should always use {} for if().

Comment: It only makes a difference if a certain number is 1000000 and not any other value.

Comment: @nimsson, just copy the correctly formatted code that is posted in the question into your code. everything will work

Comment: @nimsson Relax a little for now and watch what just happened. Turned out to be such a better human-behavior lesson than a programming one. You were utterly ignoring everybody filled with reason and blind to your mistakes, the skeptical-angry answers were growing. The well-intended edit messed it all up. And so on.

Comment: @Kahler: If he had posted actual scientific timing results like I asked, people would be less skeptical!

Comment: posting video soon @staticx

Comment: @nimsson: Just look at the "slow" code version. Every time `primes[i]` is `false` the bottom loop iterates through the entire array again.

Comment: not so @Blastfurnace download my exe files and find out for yourself.

Comment: @nimsson: [Please see this pastebin](http://pastebin.com/iyEB1LB3). It's how the compiler sees the code structure as posted without parentheses. Notice how the "fast" version has an `else if(!print)` and the "slow" version just has an `else` at the same location. The code execution __is__ different.

Comment: My question is why is the `else if(!print)` faster. You'd think that one more comparison would make the code slower...@Blastfurnace

Comment: Because print is always going to be true at that point in the code.

Comment: It might have been my style. let me try that now @Blastfurnace.

Comment: Actually, my style didn't make a difference @Blastfurnace.

Comment: @Matt the extra comparison `else if(!print)` has to take some cpu cycles. `else` is just if `if(print)` is not satisfied where as the computer has to calculate both of them in the `else if(!print)`. I just don't get it. The second loop should never even be touched.

Comment: @nimsson: Do you get the same result for `numprimes` with both versions of the code?

Comment: @nimsson: Okay, that's a head-scratcher. Let me go run your code on my machine...

Comment: @Blastfurnace I posted the exe files in my question.

Comment: @nimsson: On my machine, when I pass the value 100 on the command line the "fast" version of your code says `numprimes` is `25` and the "slow" version says there are `1900`, clearly the code execution is different. When I add the `-np` option both just say there are `0` primes.

Comment: @nimsson, because print is always true, when you are doing `else if (!print)` it's never executing that second loop. When you have `else` it's always executing that second loop.

Comment: I have a c++ version of the same thing @Blastfurnace. It uses the same block to print except it uses cout.

Comment: here's an idea @Blastfurnace remove the offending else. That's what's in my c++ version. That should clear up a few issues.

Comment: @nimsson Could be? Why not just put a printf in there and see if it ever gets called. It won't, because its inside another `if (print)`.

Comment: @nimsson: If you change the `if(skipprint)` in the C++ code to an `else` it would match the form of original "slow" code snippet. Seriously, the lack of parentheses here dramatically changes the meaning of your code.

Comment: I know @Blastfurnace the *slow* version does not glitch in this one I believe.

Comment: never mind; it does @Blastfurnace. I think your original answer was right now, but it was not my coding style.

Comment: @nimsson: I've gotten very defensive with my parenthese over time. It's better to add too many and be sure the code expresses your intent, especially when you can't trust indentation to match related code blocks.

Comment: @nimsson: Your error is very famous; this is called the *dangling else problem*. The moral of the story here is, first, always use braces when dealing with multiple `if` and `else` clauses, and second, **step through your code in a debugger when something appears to be not working correctly**.

Comment: Yes; perfect explaination @EricLippert.