# how to find execution time of while-loop not total program

Tags: c, algorithm, time-complexity

```
int i=0;
while(i<=100)
{
    printf("hello world....\n");
    i++;
}
```

For the above program, how can I find the total time of execution of `while` loop.

Comment: The body of the loop is not executed.

Comment: For loop execution `while( i <= 100 )`. It's already been answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5248915/execution-time-of-c-program

Comment: Could have searched before asking the question. This has already been answered.

Comment: That will be executed really, really fast :-) You probably want to change `while(i>=100)` into `while(i <= 100)`

Comment: thank you frnds. i have searched before but i did'nt find may be I am lack of searching knowledge . anyway thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In header file time.h have that function. you can use that.
You can see there is a clock_t variable called start which calls a clock() function.
try this:

```
clock_t start = clock();
for ( i = 0; i < 100; i++ )
            rand();
    printf ( "%f\n", ( (double)clock() - start ) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC );
```

it will give you execution time. for this check your conditioj in while loop. it should "< 100" i think. check this code it will work for you.

Comment: loop will not execute `i=0` and in while loop it says `i>=100`

Comment: i mentioned it in edit check this. its a running code.

Comment: great yeap now it works

Comment: now its working thanks