# How to know the execution time of a program

Tags: python, c, runtime, code-snippets

How to print the execution time in seconds of C or Python Code?

Comment: Or [Execution time of C program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5248915/execution-time-of-c-program)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In C , just wrap your code with this code.You will get the execution time in seconds.

```
#include <time.h>
{
 clock_t start, end;
 double cpu_time_used;
 start = clock();

 /* Your Code */

 end = clock();
 cpu_time_used = ((double) (end - start)) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
 printf("The Execution Time In Seconds is : %lf",cpu_time_used);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use datetime in Python for that.

```
start_time = datetime.datetime.now()
<your program/ lines of code in the Python script/program>
-----
-----
-----
print (datetime.datetime.now() - start_time)
```

This should give the time. You can also use timeit.timeit() I guess.