# how to calculate stack usage and execution time in c

Tags: c

I am trying to calculate stack usage and execution time of below program,but facing difficulty to understand ,could anyone please tell me how to calculate it..

> addition of two number in c

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
  int a,b,c;
  printf("enter two numbers\n)";
  scanf("%d%d",&a,&b);
  c=a+b;
  printf("sum of two numbers %d",c);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: For such a trivial program, actual execution time will likely be buried in general noise of process and OS overhead.  For stack usage, it may be best to examine the code's assembly.

Comment: [Execution time of a c program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5248915/execution-time-of-c-program) but in the future, please ask one question per question and I recommend showing a bit more effort/research than this.

Comment: How manually we can calculate while seeing the code?

Comment: @Asha What do you wan to manually calculate?

Comment: I want to calculate stack usage of a particular program..

Comment: how much stack is required for that particular program..