If CLOCKS_PER_SEC is fixed at 1,000,000 on POSIX, then why do we rely on execution time calculated using clock()?
Someone please help me to understand how to accurately calculate the execution time of the programs using clock() and CLOCKS_PER_SEC functions.
If CLOCKS_PER_SEC is fixed at 1,000,000 on POSIX ( regardless of the actual precision of hardware clock), then why do we rely on execution time calculated using clock()? It should be inaccurate.

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/5249150/4386427

From the POSIX clock reference: "The clock() function shall return the implementation's best approximation to the processor time used by the process since the beginning of an implementation-defined era related only to the process invocation." (emphasis mine)

With the above said, the clock() function isn't a good time-keeper. It's definition is not portable outside of POSIX, it's inaccurate (as you mention), and there are better functions for timing in a process.

Dear all contributors if it is so inaccurate and useless then what is the point of having it in the standard library?

Did you read the answer provided in link shared by @4386427? It seems to explain properly.

There was a time when timing to the nearest microsecond was good (about the same era as the birth of Unix). These days many CPUs have something that approximates a 64bit system timer running at full clock speed (although you have to allow for systematic errors in a multitasking environment). Timer resolution isn't everything. If you care about benchmarking code then it is unwise to time something much shorter than 1s unless on bare metal (clock resolution 1ppm, systematic error from multitasking OS ~0.1% or so).

@kiner_shah Nu sure what your comment means

@4386427, oh don't worry, was just asking OP to read the answer provided in the link shared by you.

@kiner_shah oh... now I see... your comment was actually for OP. I was just referenced as "poster of the link" :-)

@kiner_shah Yes I did.
