# How to use NSTimer to check the performance of function?

Tags: iphone, functional-testing

How to use NSTimer to check the performance of function?
Actually, I am making a dylib which is Cydia Software. 
I have found many resources, but I still don't know which part of my functions slow down whole 
program. I need someone's help....

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try and use Instruments with time profiler? This will give you plenty of information without the hassle of having to come up with a timer based handcrafted profiler.

Have a look at [this article](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/InstrumentsUserGuide/Built-InInstruments/Built-InInstruments.html) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

The clock function returns a tick of type clock_t that is defined by a CLOCKS_PER_SEC constants. Posix requires this value to be 1000000 ticks per second (microsecond), but that is not guaranteed by ANSI-C. So, you should check CLOCKS_PER_SEC to see the actually resolution on your platform.

duplicated question: [How to measure time in milliseconds using ANSI C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/361363/how-to-measure-time-in-milliseconds-using-ansi-c)

Comment: actually, I am using dylib that cannot be checked by this directly. I think I need a timing code like NSTimer. I found a source code from your reference.