# How do I fix a chrono fatal error for a C program using gcc as the compilier?

Tags: c, gcc

I'm trying to design a code in C for a class that will tell me how long it takes to run a function in milliseconds. My professor suggested that I use chrono to do this, but I can't get chrono to work on my system. When I try something like the code below, I get "fatal error: chrono: No such file or directory."

```
#include <chrono>
int main()
{
   return 0;
}
```

I have tried the following compilier commands, but they aren't working

```
gcc prog.c
```

or

```
gcc -std=c++11 prog.c
```

(This works if I change the program to prog.cc but my professor requires that all programs be .c).

I am using PuTTY provided by my school, a gcc compiler, and C as the programming language.

Please help!

Answer (score 1):

`<chrono>` is a C++ library - you can't use that for your code if you're compiling with `gcc`, but you could probably make it work if you compile with `g++`. (Note that this compiler is more picky; your C code will likely need some editing if it's more than just an empty `main()`.)

Maybe use `<time.h>` instead? It contains several similar functions related to time keeping.

Comment: Can time.h be used to find the time in milliseconds? My professor says the output has to be in milliseconds.

Comment: Sure, it works in milliseconds too, [according to this answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10192994/7431860)

Comment: @NickReed -- that answer refers to <sys/time.h> and gettimeofday, which is POSIX specific.  <time.h> (part of the C standard) only has time (giving time in seconds) and clock (giving clock ticks, with unspecified accuracy), and only in C11 adds timespec_get which gives time in nanoseconds.