os.clock() in lua return wrong value
I'm using os.clock in lua to measure working time of a function. I add debug log like below
test = function()
  print(">>>>>>>>start record id: ", record_id, "clock: ", os.clock())

  ...
  body
  ...

  print(">>>>>>>>end record id: ", record_id, "clock: ", os.clock())
end

I also use <your commadn> | ts "[%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S]" to monitor output console.
When monitoring output console, I figure out time stamp in ts command is different from os.clock() result in lua.
[2024-07-01 22:46:29] >>>>>>>>start record id:  2   clock:  0.143632
[2024-07-01 22:46:29] >>>>>>>>end record id:    2   clock:  0.152762
[2024-07-01 22:46:29] >>>>>>>>start record id:  3   clock:  0.152998
...
...
[2024-07-01 22:50:25] >>>>>>>>end record id:    3639    clock:  48.124877
[2024-07-01 22:50:25] >>>>>>>>start record id:  3640    clock:  48.125138
[2024-07-01 22:50:25] >>>>>>>>end record id:    3640    clock:  48.137237

Following above result logs, to log 3639 records, ts command needs 4 minutes to complete but os.clock() only needs 48 seconds.
Do I misunderstanding about os.clock() result?
Expected
I just wanna know how much time do my system need to log 1 record. Because it's very fast so I use os.clock() but the result make me confuse

Effectively a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7335920/what-specifically-are-wall-clock-time-user-cpu-time-and-system-cpu-time-in-uni. os.clock() is in CPU time, ts shows wall time. Your CPU is idling, because logging is I/O bottlenecked.

So how can I measure time to log 1 record in milisecons in lua? os.clock() is just return CPU times of the process. Do u have any suggestions?

our source follow is: a record will be log in C function and then it will be sync to an application which written by lua. I wanna calculate time sync from the beginning in C function to the end in application

It seems that LuaSocket can be a good answer: https://w3.impa.br/~diego/software/luasocket/socket.html#gettime
You can have even more precise timing with LuaPosix: https://luaposix.github.io/luaposix/modules/posix.time.html#clock_gettime but for some I cannot make it work on my machine (the clock_gettime function returns a number instead of a table with the seconds and the nanoseconds). So LuaSocket may be a safer choice.
With LuaSocket:
local socket = require('socket')

test = function()
  print(">>>>>>>>start record id: ", record_id)
  local t = socket.gettime()

  ...
  body
  ...

  print(">>>>>>>>end record id: ", record_id, "time taken: ", socket.gettime() - t)
end


With LuaPosix:
local posix = require('posix')

test = function()
  print(">>>>>>>>start record id: ", record_id)
  local t = posix.clock_gettime(0)

  ...
  body
  ...

  local t2 = posix.clock_gettime(0)

  local elapsed_time = end_time.tv_sec - start_time.tv_sec + (end_time.tv_nsec - start_time.tv_nsec)

  print(">>>>>>>>end record id: ", record_id, "time taken: ", elapsed_time)
end

Here I take the first timestamp after the first print, so it doesn't count in the time measured. But if it is part of what you want to measure, you would need to put it before.

Hi, I have 2 points confuse:

Do socket.gettime() and posix.clock_gettime can measure timestamp in another process. My flow code is: a record will be log in C function and then it will be sync to an application which written by lua. I wanna calculate time sync from the beginning in C function to the end in application.
My system report module 'posix' not found when I import the module. I can't update luajit version. How to bypass it


@LV_Embedded You could get same time measurments in your C process with clock_gettime (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10192903/time-in-milliseconds-in-c) and log them along side the lua measurments, the differences would be the time taken.
For the inclusion of the posix module, you need to install the lib if it is not on your computer, using luarocks is the best way : luarocks install luaposix.
