# millisecond precision timing of functions in C - crossplatform

Tags: c, time, profiling, cross-platform

Is there a way to get milliseconds precision, accurate (at least within a few ms) times in C using a cross-platform approach?

on a POSIX system I can use sys/time.h, but that is not cross-platform.

the stdlib time() function only gives second level precision

Comment: you can always check the current time in a loop.... can you provide more information including why and what did you try?

Comment: Can you just run the subroutine 1000 times in a loop, measure the time in seconds, and then divide by 1000. BTW, a millisecond is a *long* time in a processor.

Comment: This was for timing algorithms that might run in the ~50ms to 10 seconds range

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I haven't found a cross-platform solution to measuring time in C, per se. However, what I do is use almost identical functions for Unix and Windows. I created this [gist](https://gist.github.com/erichschroeter/8199129) because I always have to re-look this up every time. In short:

#### Unix

```
#include <time.h>

long diff_micro(struct timespec *start, struct timespec *end)
{
    /* us */
    return ((end->tv_sec * (1000000)) + (end->tv_nsec / 1000)) -
        ((start->tv_sec * 1000000) + (start->tv_nsec / 1000));
}

long diff_milli(struct timespec *start, struct timespec *end)
{
    /* ms */
    return ((end->tv_sec * 1000) + (end->tv_nsec / 1000000)) -
        ((start->tv_sec * 1000) + (start->tv_nsec / 1000000));
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    struct timespec start, end;

    clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &start);

    // Activity to be timed
    sleep(1000);

    clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &end);

    printf("%ld us\n", diff_micro(&start, &end));
    printf("%ld ms\n", diff_milli(&start, &end));

    return 0;
}
```

[source for Unix solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/380446/561624)

#### Win32

```
#include <Windows.h>

long diff_micro(LARGE_INTEGER *start, LARGE_INTEGER *end)
{
    LARGE_INTEGER Frequency, elapsed;

    QueryPerformanceFrequency(&Frequency); 
    elapsed.QuadPart = end->QuadPart - start->QuadPart;

    elapsed.QuadPart *= 1000000;
    elapsed.QuadPart /= Frequency.QuadPart;

    return elapsed.QuadPart;
}

long diff_milli(LARGE_INTEGER *start, LARGE_INTEGER *end)
{
    LARGE_INTEGER Frequency, elapsed;

    QueryPerformanceFrequency(&Frequency); 
    elapsed.QuadPart = end->QuadPart - start->QuadPart;

    elapsed.QuadPart *= 1000;
    elapsed.QuadPart /= Frequency.QuadPart;

    return elapsed.QuadPart;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    LARGE_INTEGER StartingTime, EndingTime;

    QueryPerformanceCounter(&StartingTime);

    // Activity to be timed
    Sleep(1000);

    QueryPerformanceCounter(&EndingTime);

    printf("%ld us\n", diff_micro(&StartingTime, &EndingTime));
    printf("%ld ms\n", diff_milli(&StartingTime, &EndingTime));

    return 0;
}
```

[source used for Win32 solution](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dn553408(v=vs.85).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:-

```
#include <time.h>
clock_t uptime = clock() / (CLOCKS_PER_SEC / 1000);
```

See this [**Link**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/361363/how-to-measure-time-in-milliseconds-using-ansi-c)

Comment: `clock` gives the CPU time, not real time. It stops on blocking, and goes faster if multi-threaded.

Answer (score 0):

The best way is using [std::chrono](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/chrono)

```
#include <chrono>

...

auto begin = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();

...

auto end = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
elapsedTime = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(end - begin).count();
```