# C: Different implementation of clock() in Windows and other OS?

Tags: c, linux, windows, macos, clock

I had to write a very simple console program for university that had to measure the time required to make an input.

Therefor I used `clock()` in front and after an `fgets()`call. When running on my Windows computer it worked perfectly. However when running on my friends Mac-Book and Linux-PC it gave extremely small results (a few micro seconds of time only).

I tried the following code on all 3 OS:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <unistd.h>

void main()
{
    clock_t t;

    printf("Sleeping for a bit\n");

    t = clock();

    // Alternatively some fgets(...)
    usleep(999999);

    t = clock() - t;

    printf("Processor time spent: %lf", ((double)t) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC);
}
```

On windows the output shows 1 second (or the amount of time you took to type when using `fgets`), on the other two OS not much more than 0 seconds.

Now my question is why there is such a difference in implementation of `clock()` on these OS. For windows it seems like the clock keeps ticking while the thread is sleeping/waiting but for Linux and Mac isn't?

Edit:
Thank you for the answers so far guys, so it's just Microsoft's faulty implementation really.

Could anyone please answer my last question:

**Also is there a way to measure what I wanted do measure on all 3 systems using C-standard libraries since `clock()` only seems to work this way on Windows?**

Comment: Take a look at the manual: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/clock.3.html The windows box is off its rocker, the others are ok. (It should approximate the processor-time used, not the wall-clock-time elapsed.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we [look at the source code](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/Libc/Libc-997.90.3/gen/FreeBSD/clock.c) for `clock()` on Mac OS X, we see that it is implemented using `getrusage`, and reads `ru_utime + ru_stime`. These two fields [measure CPU time used by the process (or by the system, on behalf of the process)](http://www.makelinux.net/alp/062). This means that if `usleep` (or `fgets`) causes the OS to swap in a different program for execution until something happens, then any amount of real time (also called "wall time", as in "wall clock") elapsed does not count against the value that `clock()` returns on Mac OS X. You could probably dig in and find something similar in Linux.

On Windows, however, `clock()` [returns the amount of wall time](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4e2ess30.aspx) elapsed since the start of the process.

In pure C, I am not aware of a function available on OS X, Linux and Windows that will return wall time with a sub-second precision (time.h being fairly limited). You have [`GetSystemTimeAsFileTime`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724397(v=vs.85).aspx) on Windows that will return you time in slices of 100ns, and [`gettimeofday`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/gettimeofday.2.html) from BSD that will return time to a microsecond precision.

If second-precision is acceptable to you, you could use [`time(NULL)`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_date_and_time_functions).

If C++ is an option, you could use one of the clocks from [`std::chrono`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/chrono/) to get time to the desired precision.

Comment: Thank you, I will indeed use `time()` and `difftime()` now to solve this issue. It's not exactly the precision I was looking for, but oh my.

Answer (score 5):

You're encountering [a known bug](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/Feedback/Details/860388) in Microsoft's C Runtime. Even though the behavior is not conforming to any ISO C standard, it won't be fixed. From the bug report:

> However, we have opted to avoid reimplementing clock() in such a way that it might return time values advancing faster than one second per physical second, as this change would silently break programs depending on the previous behavior (and we expect there are many such programs).

Comment: @Deduplicator: Remembered. The official documentation actually says it returns the wall time (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4e2ess30.aspx). But it doesn't mention that's nonconforming.

Answer (score 1):

On Linux, you should read [time(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/time.7.html). It suggests to use the POSIX 2001 [clock_gettime](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/clock_gettime.html) which should exist on recent MacOSX (and on Linux). On Linux, running on not too old hardware (e.g. less than 6 years old laptop or desktop), `clock_gettime` gives good accuracy, typically dozens of microseconds or better. It gives measures with seconds and nanoseconds (in a `struct timespec`), but I don't expect the nanosecond figure to be very accurate.

Indeed, [clock(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/clock.3.html) is told to be conforming to...

> C89, C99, POSIX.1-2001.  POSIX requires that CLOCKS_PER_SEC equals
>          1000000 independent of the actual resolution.

At last, several framework libraries provide functions (wrapping target specific system functions) to measure time. Look into [POCO](http://pocoproject.org/) (in C++) or [Glib](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/) (from GTK & Gnome in C).

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend you try to create your own `clock()` function. If you want to use it, I have created this simple function that resembles the `clock()` function on Linux:

```
clock_t clock_unix_like_systems(void)
{   
    struct timespec current_time;
    if (clock_gettime(CLOCK_BOOTTIME,&current_time) != 0) return -1;
    return current_time.tv_sec * CLOCKS_PER_SEC + current_time.tv_nsec /(1000000000 /CLOCKS_PER_SEC); 
}
```

**Note:** *Remember two things about this function, 1) You can change the type of the variables. 2) You can use `errno` global variable to describe details about why a particular operation failed.*

As an example, you can use it in case you want to create the Arduino's `delay()` function from the beginning, like in the next case:

```
    int delay(int millis)
    {   
        if (millis < 0)
        {
            printf("Time must be positive");
        

    return -1;
    }
    clock_t start;int  finish;
    long int compare = (long int) millis * 1000;
    start = clock_unix_like_systems();
    while(finish <= compare) 
    {
        finish = (long int) (clock_unix_like_systems() - start);

    }
    return 0;
}
```

I hope this gonna be helpful.

Comment: For the purpose of measuring elapsed time (e.g. "`elapsed = clock() - old_clock_value`"), `gettimeofday()` (which is influenced by time adjustments and possibly leap seconds) is fundamentally unreliable. E.g. the result of `clock_unix_like_systems() - old_clock_value` could be negative.

Comment: I totally agree with you about the time adjustments influence that `gettimeofday()` has. However, the question regards a problem with the `clock()` function on Linux. If you try to get the elapsed time on Linux (i.e elapsed = clock() - old_clock_value) and use it, for example, with the `delay()` I've created before, you're gonna see that the acquired time is not the physical time that we perceive. Therefore, I'm suggesting a new `" clock() "` function that, regardless have some influence, attempts to work on Linux like `clock()` does on Windows.

Comment: I think the correct tool for measuring elapsed time on Linux is `clock_gettime(CLOCK_PROCESS_CPUTIME_ID, ...)`, especially if you want high precision and low overhead. Note that on modern systems a 1 millisecond delay is several million CPU cycles (better to ask OS for a task switch and avoid busy waiting when the delay is that long).

Comment: The `clock_gettime(CLOCK_PROCESS_CPUTIME_ID, ...)` function does not work, since `tv_sec`, from the `timespec` structure, returns zero. (In that case, you do not know how many seconds have passed). However,  I changed the clock_id  `CLOCK_PROCESS_CPUTIME_ID` to `CLOCK_REALTIME`, and I acquired the tv_sec value.  Thank you for your comment @Brendan, I've updated the code with the `clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME,...)` function.

Comment: Oops. I messed that up badly. `CLOCK_PROCESS_CPUTIME_ID` is wrong because it doesn't count time when a process is suspended. `CLOCK_REALTIME` isn't right either (affected by discontinuous jumps in the system time - the same reason `gettimeofday()` isn't right). It'd be `CLOCK_MONOTONIC_RAW`  or `CLOCK_BOOTTIME` that you'd want. Sorry.

Comment: I've uploaded the code with your suggestion. Thank you so much @Brendan, I've learned a lot from your comments.