# How to avoid compiler optimizing some operation?

Tags: c++, performance, optimization, compiler-optimization

How to avoid compiler optimizing some operation?

For example, if i implement my own `sprintf2`, i want to compare the performance of my `sprintf2` and stdlib's `sprintf`, so i wrote this code:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include<ctime>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    char c[50];
    double d=-2.532343e+23;
    int MAXN=1e8;
    time_t t1,t2,t3;

    t1=clock();

    for(int i=0;i<MAXN;i++)
        sprintf2(c,"%16.2e",d);//my own implemention of sprintf

    t2=clock();

    for(int i=0;i<MAXN;i++)
        sprintf(c,"%16.2e",d);

    t3=clock();

    printf("sprintf2:%dms\nsprintf:%dms\n",t2-t1,t3-t2);
    return 0;
}
```

It turns out:

```
sprintf2:523538ms//something big, i forgot
sprintf:0ms
```

As we know, `sprintf` costs time, and MAXN is so big, so `t3-t2` shouldn't be `0`.

As we don't use array `c`, and each time `d` is the same, so i guess compiler optimized it and `sprintf` only did **once**.

So here is the question, how can i measure the real time that 1e8`sprintf` cost?

Comment: What I often do is, after you have finished timing the operation, make sure you use the variable so it won't be optimized away (print it out).

Comment: On which compiler, which operating system, which libc, which optimizations ?

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch MSVC,Windows7,release mode with -O2 and -Ot option.

Comment: So it is time to install Linux and use GCC!

Comment: I cannot reproduce your problem with VS2013 on Win8.1 in release mode. However, have you tried making t1,t2 and t3 global  volatiles or global atomics?

Comment: Btw: Is this exactly the code you are using?

Comment: I can now reproduce your problem, when using x86 as the target platform (I'm using x64 by defaut) and `atomic` or `volatile` doesn't help :(

Comment: Well, my `sprintf2` is a little complicated, so i don't show it.

Answer (score 2):

The compiler optimized the calls to `sprintf` because you did not use the result, and because it is printing always the same number. So change also the printed number (since if you call the same `sprintf` in a loop the compiler is allowed to optimize and move the `sprintf` before the loop)

So just use the result, e.g. by computing a (meaningless) sum of some of the characters.

```
int s=0;
memset(c, 0, sizeof(c));
for(int i=0;i<MAXN;i++) {
    sprintf2(c,"%16.2e",d+i*1.0e-9);
    s+=c[i%8];
}; 
t2=clock();
for(int i=0;i<MAXN;i++) {
    sprintf(c,"%16.2e",d+i*1.0e-9);
    s+=c[i%8];
}
t3=clock();

printf("sprintf2:%dms\nsprintf:%dms\ns=%d\n",t2-t1,t3-t2,s);

t3=clock();
```

then you should be able to benchmark and to compile. You probably want to display the time cost of every call:

```
printf("sprintf2:%f ms\nsprintf:%f ms\n",
       1.0e3*(t2-t1)/(double)maxn, 1.0e3*(t3-t2)/(double)maxn);
```

since POSIX requires that `CLOCKS_PER_SEC` equals 1000000, so a `clock` tick is one microsecond.

BTW, `MAXN` (which should be spelt in lower cases, all uppercases is conventionally for macros!) could be some input (otherwise a clever optimizing compiler could unroll the loop at compile time), e.g.

```
 int main(int argc, char**argv) {
   int maxn = argc>1 ? atoi(argv[1]) : 1000000;
```

Notice that when you are benchmarking, you really should ask the compiler to optimize with `-O2`. **Measuring the speed of unoptimized code is meaningless**.

And you can always look at the assembler code (e.g. `gcc -O2 -fverbose-asm -S`) and check that `sprintf2` and `sprintf` are indeed called in a loop.

BTW on my Linux Debian/Sid/x86-64  i7 3770K desktop:

```
 /// file b.c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char**argv) {
  int s=0;
  char buf[50];
  memset(buf, 0, sizeof(buf));
  int maxn = (argc>1) ? atoi(argv[1]) : 1000000;
  clock_t t1 = clock();
  for (int i=0; i<maxn; i++) {
    snprintf(buf, sizeof(buf), "%12.3f",
     123.45678+(i*0.01)*(i%117));
    s += buf[i%8];
  };
  clock_t t2 = clock();
  printf ("maxn=%d s=%d deltat=%.3f sec, each iter=%.3f µsec\n",
      maxn, s, (t2-t1)*1.0e-6, ((double)(t2-t1))/maxn);
  return 0;
}
```

compiled as `gcc -std=c99 -Wall -O3 b.c -o b` (GCC is 4.9.2, Glibc is 2.19) gives the following consistent timings:

```
% time ./b 4000000               
maxn=4000000 s=191871388 deltat=2.180 sec, each iter=0.545 µsec
./b 4000000  2.18s user 0.00s system 99% cpu 2.184 total
% time ./b 7000000
maxn=7000000 s=339696631 deltat=3.712 sec, each iter=0.530 µsec
./b 7000000  3.71s user 0.00s system 99% cpu 3.718 total
% time ./b 6000000                             
maxn=6000000 s=290285020 deltat=3.198 sec, each iter=0.533 µsec
./b 6000000  3.20s user 0.00s system 99% cpu 3.203 total
% time ./b 6000000
maxn=6000000 s=290285020 deltat=3.202 sec, each iter=0.534 µsec
./b 6000000  3.20s user 0.00s system 99% cpu 3.207 total
```

BTW, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27178789/841108) regarding Windows `clock` implementation (which might be perceived as buggy). You might be as happy as I am with installing and using Linux on your machine (I never used Windows, but I am using Unix or POSIX like systems since 1987).

Comment: Your advice is good, i also think of using the result, but after all your refactor, 1e8 `sprintf` still cost only 0ms, why? have you try running 1e8 `sprintf` on your pc?

Comment: When i test the single `sprintf`, it gave me the correct time, but when i test `sprintf` and `sprintf2` at the same time, `sprintf` just 0ms, it's strange. BTW I use MSVS2013. Anyway, your answer is helpful.

Comment: @Basile: Not wanting to start a war here, but I really don't see how that specific behavior of MVS or the C-Runttime is a reason to switch to Linux, especially as GCC is available for Windows too (there ARE valid reasons to switch to linux of course).

Comment: AFAIU the `clock` misfeature on Windows is an OS issue, not a compiler one.

Comment: But `clock` works fine in my other project, and i think MSVS is a better IDE for C++.

Answer (score 0):

At least in GCC the optimisation is stated in the documentation as not even turned on by default

> Most optimizations are only enabled if an -O level is set on the command line. Otherwise they are disabled, even if individual optimization flags are specified.

As you can read here

https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Optimize-Options.html

But I can't share this impression.

So if by not specifing an -O parameter (or for MSVC you can just set the optimisation level in the properties, I remember there was a flag "no optimisation") not the expected behaving takes place, I would say, there is no way for turning off the optimisations in a way you want it.

But remember, the compiler is doing a lot of optimisation stuff, where you can't even directly do in the code. So there isn't even a reason for "turning off everything" if it is that what you are interested in.
So by documentation the latter seems to be not possible.

Comment: Well, i use MSVC, after i turned off all the optimisation, 1e8 `sprintf` still only cost 0ms,why and how.