# Is it possible to execute a condition only after a certain amount of time in C

Tags: c, timer, conditional-statements

I am wondering if it is possible to execute a piece of code only if a condition is true for a certain amount of time.

For example :

```
if(position_goal_reached == 1) //but this should be true for 1 second)
    {do something;}
```

I don't think C is able to do that but I wanted to be sure.

Comment: You'd have to code the testing and monitoring.  It can be done, but there isn't anything built into the language that supports such an operation directly.

Comment: well... no but then also yes... you need a state machine to do it. In other words - C doesn't support it so you need to write your own code

Comment: "A certain amount of time" relative to what? The start of the execution of your program? An absolute timestamp? A timer you start elsewhere in your code?

Comment: One simple (if not very accurate) way is to monitor `clock()` result, or `time()` result. These are standard C functions.

Comment: @zr0gravity7 as I said in my code, it's clear. 
if the position is reached for a certain amount of time, in other words, if the boolean variable position_goal_reached is equal to 1 for a certain amount of time.

Comment: If you want to *specifically* do it by monitoring that variable, you can control that from another execution thread. But there are simpler ways. "I don't think C is able to" is sort of true, but you can write code in C to do it.

Comment: Every time the code changes `position_goal_reached`, it should record a timestamp. Then the `if` statement needs to compare the current time with the timestamp.

Comment: How to approach this problem would depend on whether the variable in question is only set under program control, or if it can be set by an external, asynchronous event.

Comment: In order to compute an elapsed 1 second the monitoring should be fine grained, every 1 or some millisecs. Elsewhere, if using time() to measure 1 sec interval one should syncronize with when the time changes from x to x+1.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend you to use `time()`, `sleep()`, `clock()` or `usleep()`.

**Note 1:** Remember to include `#include <unistd.h>` or/and `#include <time.h>`

**Note 2:** There are some problems with clock() if you're using [Unix-like Systems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27178789/c-different-implementation-of-clock-in-windows-and-other-os/68478530#68478530).

I think you wanna do the next:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
int main(void)
{   
    clock_t start;
    start = clock();
    int milliseconds = 1000; // The amount of milliseconds that the conditional must take (This case 1 second)
    if(position_goal_reached == 1) 
    {   start_again_if:

        do something; //What you want to do must be here
 
         if ((int)(clock() - start) < milliseconds ) goto start_again_if;
    }
}
```

I hope this gonna be helpful.