# TIME_UTC and timespec_get not declared errors with gcc installed by anaconda

Tags: c, gcc, anaconda, anaconda3

TIME_UTC and timespec_get were not declared with gcc installed by anaconda

I tried to install the latest anaconda with `cxx-compiler` and `compilers` and attempted to compile a c file, but it failed due to undeclared TIME_UTC marco and timespec_get function, which should have been included in the `time.h` file. However, my system compiler compiled the file successfully. I tried the solution from https://root-forum.cern.ch/t/error-timespec-get-has-not-been-declared-with-conda-root-package/45712/6 and made sure that packages from `conda-forge` have higher priority, but it did not work for me.

I've tried searching some other keywords but can't seem to find similar cases on Google. So any hints/suggestions are appreciated.

#### Minimal Example

We start with a simple test example `test.c`:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

// from https://stackoverflow.com/a/36095407
// Get the current time in nanoseconds
long get_nanos() {
    struct timespec ts;
    timespec_get(&ts, TIME_UTC);
    return (long)ts.tv_sec * 1000000000L + ts.tv_nsec;
}

int main() {
    // print time
    long test_time = get_nanos();
    printf("Time: %ld\n", test_time);
}
```

Create a fresh environment

```
conda create -n test_env
conda activate test_env
conda install -c conda-forge compilers cxx-compiler
gcc test.c
```

Here is the error reported by gcc

```
test.c: In function 'get_nanos':
test.c:9:9: warning: implicit declaration of function 'timespec_get' [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
    9 |         timespec_get(&ts, TIME_UTC);
      |         ^~~~~~~~~~~~
test.c:9:27: error: 'TIME_UTC' undeclared (first use in this function)
    9 |         timespec_get(&ts, TIME_UTC);
      |                           ^~~~~~~~
test.c:9:27: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
```

For reference, this is the output of `conda list` after the above commands to make sure packages are coming from conda-forge

```
# Name                    Version                   Build  Channel
_libgcc_mutex             0.1                 conda_forge    conda-forge
_openmp_mutex             4.5                       2_gnu    conda-forge
binutils                  2.39                 hdd6e379_1    conda-forge
binutils_impl_linux-64    2.39                 he00db2b_1    conda-forge
binutils_linux-64         2.39                h5fc0e48_13    conda-forge
c-compiler                1.5.2                h0b41bf4_0    conda-forge
compilers                 1.5.2                ha770c72_0    conda-forge
cxx-compiler              1.5.2                hf52228f_0    conda-forge
fortran-compiler          1.5.2                hdb1a99f_0    conda-forge
gcc                       11.3.0              h02d0930_13    conda-forge
gcc_impl_linux-64         11.3.0              hab1b70f_19    conda-forge
gcc_linux-64              11.3.0              he6f903b_13    conda-forge
gfortran                  11.3.0              ha859ce3_13    conda-forge
gfortran_impl_linux-64    11.3.0              he34c6f7_19    conda-forge
gfortran_linux-64         11.3.0              h3c55166_13    conda-forge
gxx                       11.3.0              h02d0930_13    conda-forge
gxx_impl_linux-64         11.3.0              hab1b70f_19    conda-forge
gxx_linux-64              11.3.0              hc203a17_13    conda-forge
kernel-headers_linux-64   2.6.32              he073ed8_15    conda-forge
ld_impl_linux-64          2.39                 hcc3a1bd_1    conda-forge
libgcc-devel_linux-64     11.3.0              h210ce93_19    conda-forge
libgcc-ng                 12.2.0              h65d4601_19    conda-forge
libgfortran5              12.2.0              h337968e_19    conda-forge
libgomp                   12.2.0              h65d4601_19    conda-forge
libsanitizer              11.3.0              h239ccf8_19    conda-forge
libstdcxx-devel_linux-64  11.3.0              h210ce93_19    conda-forge
libstdcxx-ng              12.2.0              h46fd767_19    conda-forge
sysroot_linux-64          2.12                he073ed8_15    conda-forge
```

This is the version of `gcc` installed by conda

```bash
(test_env) ➜  test_dir gcc --version 
gcc (conda-forge gcc 11.3.0-19) 11.3.0
Copyright (C) 2021 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

Comment: I think I may have narrowed down the problems to differences in time.h from glibc. The system-level `time.h` from `/usr/include/time.h` contains definition for TIME_UTC and timespec_get, but the version provided by anaconda, which is found at `~/anaconda3/envs/test_env/x86_64-conda-linux-gnu/sysroot/usr/include/time.h`, does not provide such definitions.

Comment: `timespec_get` is a relatively new C++ thing.  I'd try the function `clock_gettime` and the macro `CLOCK_REALTIME`.

Comment: @Steve Summit, But it's part of C11, and they're using a gcc from 2021. My gcc from 2019 supports it.

Comment: @ikegami Okay, my bad, thanks!  (But I stand by my suggestion that OP might try `clock_gettime`.)

Comment: @SteveSummit Thanks for the pointer, but I am trying to compile a large library. So it'd be best if I can avoid manually patching every single occurence.

Comment: @RogerQ. Ever get this solved?

Comment: Unfortunately no. I ended up following the suggestions from @SteveSummit and manually replacing every occurrence of `timespec_get` with `clock_gettime`, which is an ugly patch but it works. An interesting finding that I got was that this behavior *does not* exhibit when I use the slow default conda solver instead of mamba.